# Selenium WebDriver access a sub element

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I have a `div` with a unique ID. Under that `div` are a bunch of `span` elements that have `className=foo`.  There are  several `span` elements with `className=foo` but they are unique to each `div` (if that's clear).  So my Selenium code first gets the unique `div` as a web element then tries to take that element and get by class name the `span` like so

```
element = sDriver.findElement(By.id("c_"+cID)); 
String sTest = element.findElement(By.className("actions")).getText();
```

On the second line it throws an exception every time

```
org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up
Command duration or timeout: 22 milliseconds
```

Do I misunderstand how to get that `span` from under a unique `div`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nope you'right accessing the span but the problem is that the Dom has changed since StaleReferenceException is about (see [StaleReferenceException](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/StaleElementReferenceException.html) )

This may be caused because the page isn't loaded completely when the code starts or changes when the code is executed. You can either try to wait a little longer for the element or catch the StaleReferenceException and try again finding the div and the span.

Comment: You can also check here for [a possible solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7474518/1077279).

Comment: This seems to be it if I put in a sleep and wait a few seconds it works fine. With no good way to tell if the page has fully loaded I think unfortunately I need to just use a sleep

Comment: you may combine both a sleep and catching the exception. Try access both elements without sleep in the first place and when it fails use a sleep and try again afterwards

Comment: Works fine with catching the exception. I have a getText() and a click(). It throws the exception at getText() though it can further click. I caught the exception since nothing was wrong with my code.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is not fancy but it works like a Swiss watch (in my situation of course). So my code is calling the parent element in a loop looking for different child elements in it. Nothing got changed at all - just simple querying and the exception began to occur. So! I've added the Thread.Sleep(2000) command before every search of parent element and it solver the problem. Not elegant but works every time with minimum code to debug afterwards.