# Selenium Webdriver finding an element in a sub-element

Tags: python, xpath, selenium

I am trying to search for an element in a sub-element with Selenium (Version 2.28.0), but selenium des not seem to limit its search to the sub-element. Am I doing this wrong or is there a way to use element.find to search a sub-element?

For an example I created a simple test webpage with this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div class=div title=div1>
            <h1>My First Heading</h1>
            <p class='test'>My first paragraph.</p>
        </div>
        <div class=div title=div2>
            <h1>My Second Heading</h1>
            <p class='test'>My second paragraph.</p>
        </div>
        <div class=div title=div3>
            <h1>My Third Heading</h1>
            <p class='test'>My third paragraph.</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

My python (Version 2.6) code looks like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

# Open the test page with this instance of Firefox

# element2 gets the second division as a web element
element2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@title='div2']")

# Search second division for a paragraph with a class of 'test' and print the content
print element2.find_element_by_xpath("//p[@class='test']").text 
# expected output: "My second paragraph."
# actual output: "My first paragraph."
```

If I run:

```
print element2.get_attribute('innerHTML')
```

It returns the html from the second division. So selenium is not limiting its search to element2.

I would like to be able to find a sub-element of element2. This post suggests my code should work [Selenium WebDriver access a sub element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8836712/selenium-webdriver-access-a-sub-element) but his problem was caused by a time-out issue.

Can anyone help me understand what is happening here?

Answer (score 192, accepted):

If you start an XPath expression with `//`, it begins searching from the root of document. To search relative to a particular element, you should prepend the expression with `.` instead:

```
element2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@title='div2']")
element2.find_element_by_xpath(".//p[@class='test']").text
```

Comment: This is an unfortunate design error in WebDriver that has been enshrined as a feature.  All other `element.find_element_by_whatever()` methods in WebDriver perform the the search *within the context of the specified element*.  find_element_by_xpath() does not.  [Selenium bug #403](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=403) goes into more detail.

Comment: That's not design error of WebDriver, that's what XPath specification demands.

Comment: That's definitely not a design error--it's how all DOM selections work in javascript...

Comment: I recommend this site to learn different XPath commands - https://www.scientecheasy.com/2019/08/xpath-axes.html

Answer (score 8):

Use the following:

```
element2 = driver.find_element_by_cssselector("css=div[title='div2']")
element2.find_element_by_cssselector("p[@class='test']").text
```

Please let me know if you have any problems.

Comment: `.text` doesn't return text value for anchor tag. this one does `element.get_attribute("text")`

Comment: `find_element_by_css_selector`

Comment: 2023 answer requires https://stackoverflow.com/a/72854301/7067224

Answer (score 5):

I guess,we need use method "By" from webdriver.common.by when use "driver.find_element".

So...the code must be:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

element2 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@title='div2']")
element2.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//p[@class='test']").text
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you search for element or tag in CSS subclass and I believe that it works for multilevel situation as well:

Sample HTML:

```html
<li class="meta-item">
 <span class="label">Posted:</span>
 <time class="value" datetime="2019-03-22T09:46:24+01:00" pubdate="pubdate">22.03.2019 u 09:46</time>
</li>
```

This is how you would get `pubdate` tag value for example.

```
published = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('li>time').get_attribute('datetime')
```

Answer (score 0):

Chrome Webdriver :

```
element = driver.find_element_by_id("ParentElement")
localElement = element.find_element_by_id("ChildElement")
print(localElement.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

***Find The Child of any Elements***

```
parent = browser.find_element(by=By.XPATH,value='value of XPATH of Parents')
    child=parent.find_elements(by=By.TAG_NAME,value='value of child path')
```