# find element inside element selenium python chrome driver

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm facing a issue when I try to get element inside of an element. I tried 2 methods to achieve this but unfortunately didn't get success.

```
element_list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='WGGO WKFO']//ul//li[@class='WO0F WHHO WI5 WF2F']//div[@class='WP0F WN0F']//div[@class='WDQY']//ul[@class='WHDR WCQY']")
```

above code get all the list of DOM elements list.

Method 1:

```
for element in element_list:
    element_text = element.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='WP0F WN0F']//div[@class='WDQY']//ul[@class='WHDR WCQY']").text
    print(element_text)
```

when I tried this it always return me first element's text instead of respective element text.

while searching I found a link where someone asked same as I want.

> [Selenium Webdriver finding an element in a sub-element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049983/selenium-webdriver-finding-an-element-in-a-sub-element)

when I tried `p0deje's` Answer it gives me blank array.

```
element_text = element.find_elements_by_xpath(".//div[@class='WP0F WN0F']//div[@class='WDQY']//ul[@class='WHDR WCQY']").text
```

Result: `[]`

please suggest me what can I do to achieve this, How can I get an element detail inside an element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem with your code on this line:
`element_text = element.find_elements_by_xpath(".//div[@class='WP0F WN0F']//div[@class='WDQY']//ul[@class='WHDR WCQY']").text` ist that find elements retunes a list, and a list has no .text attribute.
try iterating over the returned list:

```py
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='WGGO WKFO']//ul//li[@class='WO0F WHHO WI5 WF2F']//div[@class='WP0F WN0F']//div[@class='WDQY']//ul[@class='WHDR WCQY']")
#as a list comprehention
element_text= [element.text for element in elements]
#or as a for loop
element_text=[]
for element in elements:
    element_text.append(element.text)
```

Comment: even this line of code returns also a empty array 
`elements = element.find_elements_by_xpath(".//div[@class='WP0F WN0F']//div[@class='WDQY']//ul[@class='WHDR WCQY']")`

Comment: @Rana.Amir yes sorry i typed element when i ment driver. ive updated the code se if it works

Comment: it's working fine but when I want to right click on element instead of text it always clicked on first element. :(

`elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='WGGO WKFO']//ul//li[@class='WO0F WHHO WI5 WF2F']//div[@class='WP0F WN0F']//div[@class='WDQY']//ul[@class='WHDR WCQY']")`


`new_elements= [element for element in elements]`

`for element in new_elements:
    action = ActionChains(driver)
    action.move_to_element(element).perform();
    action.context_click().perform()`

Comment: think you should do :
`for element in new_elements:
    actionChains.context_click(element).perform()`

Answer (score 1):

`element_list` already holds all the elements you want to print, i.e. the `element_text`. You can't use `WebElement` to locate itself, the reason it didn't fail with `NoSuchElementException` is that when using `xpath` to locate element from another element you need to specify current context `.`

```
find_element_by_xpath('.//div')
```

Iterate over `element_list`

```
for element in element_list:
    print(element.text)
```

Or if you really want to split it because you have more actions on the parent list you can use (note she shortened `element_list` `xpath`)

```
element_list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='WGGO WKFO']//ul//li[@class='WO0F WHHO WI5 WF2F']")
for element in element_list:
    element_text = element.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@class='WP0F WN0F']//div[@class='WDQY']//ul[@class='WHDR WCQY']").text
    print(element_text)
```