# i've a strange behaviour in using lxml.etree.HTML

Tags: python, python-3.x, lxml, elementtree, lxml.html

i'm unable to understand why in the below code:

1. i put all the parsed page in x (ok)
2. i create in l1 a list of items i'm interesting in with x.xpath (ok)
3. i cycle through the elements in l1 assigning every single element to l2
4. i try to find in l3 an element i'm interesting in with l2.xpath but I DON'T UNDERSTAND why i don't obtain in l3 only a list of one element, the one i should found in l2 element, but a list with all elements i would find if i would write x.xpath, in other words sub-elements from the entire page and not only inside the l2 element

Someone know the reason and can explain me the solution? Thank you.

```
from lxml.etree import HTML
from requests import Session

z = Session()
z.params = {"filter[entry_type]": "business"}
x = z.get("https://www.local.ch/it/q", params={"where": 'Chiasso'}).text
x = HTML(x)
l1 = x.xpath("//*[starts-with(@class, 'js-entry-card-container')]")
for l2 in l1:
   l3 = l2.xpath("//*[starts-with(@class, 'lui-margin-vertical-zero')]")
```

Comment: Could you please a minimal sample for input file to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sorry, i forget always something. You can simply create a text file named Svizzera.txt with a line with "Chiasso" and a second blank line.

Comment: Why not hardcode that string in the question instead of having the code try to read a file at all, then? A good [mre] is the shortest possible thing that can be run _without changes_ to see the same problem; needing to create an input file is a change.

Comment: Code changed...

Comment: This is near the minimal possible.

Comment: Better, indeed. The only thing that's not great about this as-currently-written is that one has to inspect the content of the linked page before the question is understandable (and answers can be learned from)-- an ideal knowledge base entry will last indefinitely, even if off-site resources change / links break / etc.

Comment: Anyhow, in terms of the problem you're having -- `//*` is different from `.//*`; if you want to search only from `l1`, you need to start with `.//` and not `//` (which explicitly tells the xpath interpreter to search the whole page, not just from the current element).

Comment: ...so even though you aren't using selenium, this is the same problem as the one encountered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049983/selenium-webdriver-finding-an-element-in-a-sub-element

Comment: @CharlesDuffy i don't know use of `.//*` was different from `//*` if i start from a sub element with lxml.etree. now i know and the problem is solved. instead i understand with selenium is different. really i've used more it. thanks. and about the code this is the minimal example, the whole code for the data base construction is different.