# Selenium StaleElementReferenceException error & pageload complete code is not constant. Click on element doesn't work

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, selenium

I would like to thank the stackoverflow community for all the help. I have been recently trying to handle “StaleElementReferenceException”, but can’t find one solution that fits all. Many members of the stackoverflow community suggested using following code for StaleElementReferenceException.
Please click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12967541/how-to-avoid-staleelementreferenceexception-in-selenium) for more details on the code.
This code sometimes works but not all the time for my applications.

So I took one more approach wait for dom to load. However, that didn’t solve the problem either. So I had to hack in my code to make it work, but I know this is not the best way of solving the problem and my code has many flaws. If someone can help me solve StaleElementReferenceException and page load problem.

```
Check for page load code 
public void pReady() {

      JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;

      //Initially bellow given if condition will check ready state of page.
      if (js.executeScript("return document.readyState").toString().equals("complete")){ 

       System.out.println("Page Is loaded.");
       return; 
      } 

      //This loop will rotate for 25 times to check If page Is ready after every 6 second.
      //You can replace your value with 25 If you wants to Increase or decrease wait time.
      for (int i=0; i<25; i++){ 
       try {
        Thread.sleep(6000);
        }catch (InterruptedException e) {} 
       //To check page ready state.
       if (js.executeScript("return document.readyState").toString ().equals("complete")){ 
        break; 
       }   
      }
     }
```

This didn't fix either as after DOM is load there seems to be some other jquery in background and page refresh few more times.

Please check my code

```
public void newpagebutton() {
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(by.id("abc")));
    try {
        pReady();
    } finally {
        if (retryingFindClick(by.id("abc"))) {
        log.info ("Submit For Request Completed.. Moving to Main Page");
    } else{
        Log.error("Submit For Request not enable");
        return;
    } try {
        WebElement sub = driver.findElement(by.id("abc"));
        while (sub.isDisplayed()) {
            retryingFindClick(by.id("abc"));
        }
    } catch (StaleElementReferenceException e) {

    }
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(by.id("abc")));

}
```

}

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

StaleElementReferenceException occurs when the element is no more accessible. From your script, looks like you are accessing the element id twice - once in wait and once again. That causes stale element because wait has already identified. 
Try doing like:(psuedo code)
ele = driver.findElement(by.id("abc"));
wait.until(ele.clickable)
finally perform operations.

Find elements only once in your script and use it across the script.

Comment: Try doing like:(psuedo code) ele = driver.findElement(by.id("abc")); wait.until(ele.clickable) finally perform operations.   The problem is exactly finally perform operations. When it click on the element nothing happens that's why I was using retryingFindClick, it was working last few months. However, recently that is not working, after it perform the action, page refresh. Therefore, I used the while condition. The code works as it is, but I would like to find better way of handling it.