# FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified error with selenium library in Python

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to make a web automation bot using python and selenium but I have encountered a problem/error

Here's my code

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

s=Service('C:/Users/asus/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/driverchromedriver.exe')
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
url='https://www.google.com'
browser.get(url)
```

And here's the eror I'm am encountered with

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 71, in start
    self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
  File "C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 951, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 1420, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

...implies that the program can't find the mentioned executable file *driverchromedriver.exe*

Possibly it's a typo as in it's original form the name of the **ChromeDriver** executable is **chromedriver.exe**

---

### Solution

Effectively the relevant line of code will be:

- If the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59909654/how-does-chrome-driver-interact-with-chrome-browser/59927747#59927747) executable is within *`C:/Users/asus/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/`*:

  ```
  s=Service('C:/Users/asus/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/chromedriver.exe')
  ```
- If the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53727887/what-is-benefit-of-using-chromedriver-over-webdriver-if-we-are-using-only-chrome/53744026#53744026) executable is within *`C:/Users/asus/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/driver/`*:

  ```
  s=Service('C:/Users/asus/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/driver/chromedriver.exe')
  ```

Comment: I tried this too

Comment: not working still