# Selenium with brave a chromium based browser(Version 1.33.106 Chromium: 96.0.4664.110 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Tags: python, selenium, brave

I'm a beginner level python programmer,

I am currently working on a browser automater using selenium,
but currently i'am using brave version 96.0.4664.45
and my chrome driver is'nt working properly, whereas geckodriver is working fine with firfox

error here---> [Errors with selenium library in python path and all correct with my side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70462971/errors-with-selenium-library-in-python-path-and-all-correct-with-my-side)

Pls help me as soon as possible

Comment: pls anyone help with this problem i am stuck with this issue for more than a month

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FileNotFoundError: \[WinError 2\] The system cannot find the file specified error with selenium library in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70462971/filenotfounderror-winerror-2-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To initiate a [brave](/questions/tagged/brave) browsing context you need to:

- Use the *`binary_location`* attribute to point to the brave binary location.
- Use the *chromedriver* executable to initiate the brave browser.

Code block:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.binary_location = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\BraveSoftware\Brave-Browser\Application\brave.exe'
driverService = Service('C:/Users/.../chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=driverService, options=option)
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [How to use Brave web browser with python, selenium and chromedriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57837496/how-to-use-brave-web-browser-with-python-selenium-and-chromedriver/65030379#65030379)
- [Use Selenium with Brave Browser pass service object written in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69970256/use-selenium-with-brave-browser-pass-service-object-written-in-python/69981271#69981271)
- [How to initiate Brave browser using Selenium and Python on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62626853/how-to-initiate-brave-browser-using-selenium-and-python-on-windows/62627392#62627392)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to try webdriver_manager

https://github.com/SergeyPirogov/webdriver_manager.

It helps to setup path to chromedriver.

For Chrome:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

For Chromium:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from webdriver_manager.utils import ChromeType

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager(chrome_type=ChromeType.CHROMIUM).install())
```

I suppose some of this will work for Brave.

Also, take a look at this example:

https://gist.github.com/passivebot/91d726bafc1f08eb475dd8384a3f21db