# What is the difference in chromedriver_binary and chomedriver.exe in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

From my knowledge, there are two ways to use a chrome driver with selenium in python:

1. either by downloading the chromedriver.exe, then by integrating it into the parameter:

   ```
   browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe")
   ```
2. either by installing chromedriver_binary via

   ```
   pip install chromedriver-binary
   ```

   in this case no more need to configure the instantiation of chrome driver

   ```
   browser = webdriver.Chrome()
   ```

My question is which is the most efficient method in terms of execution time? Which of these two methods do you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### chromedriver-binary

[**chromedriver-binary**](https://pypi.org/project/chromedriver-binary/) downloads and installs the chromedriver binary version 97.0.4692.36 for automated testing of webapps. The installer supports Linux, MacOS and Windows operating systems.

- To install:

  ```
  pip install chromedriver-binary
  ```
- Usage: To use chromedriver you need the following import:

  ```
  import chromedriver_binary
  ```

  This will add the executable to your PATH so it will be found. You can also get the absolute filename of the binary using:

  ```
  chromedriver_binary.chromedriver_filename
  ```

---

However with [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) ***v3.x*** you can download the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59909654/how-does-chrome-driver-interact-with-chrome-browser/59927747#59927747) and use the *key* *`executable_path`* to pass the absolute path of the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53727887/what-is-benefit-of-using-chromedriver-over-webdriver-if-we-are-using-only-chrome/53744026#53744026).

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe")
```

---

### Conclusion

There is no best practices defined neither any efficiency matrix comparing the two approaches. It's the user perspective of comfortness. The only bonus point using `executable_path` is, you don't require to install any additional package.