# Eclipse Error when trying to run in windows

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, error-handling

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable must exist: C:\chromedriver.exe
    at org.openqa.selenium.internal.Require$FileStateChecker.isFile(Require.java:315)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.checkExecutable(DriverService.java:144)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:139)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$000(ChromeDriverService.java:38)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(ChromeDriverService.java:231)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:434)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:127)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:46)
    at base.main(base.java:35)
```

Hi Guys was trying to do some practice but always this error comes up it will be really helpful if you guys can help me to understand the error. I tried setting up the selenium driver path but still error not going away. the code is on the bottom.Thank you in advance

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class base {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C://chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
        //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        WebDriverWait w =new WebDriverWait(driver,5);
        String[] itemsNeeded= {"Cucumber","Brocolli","Beetroot"};
        driver.get("https://rahulshettyacademy.com/seleniumPractise/");
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        addItems(driver,itemsNeeded);
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("img[alt='Cart']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'PROCEED TO CHECKOUT')]")).click();
        w.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("input.promoCode")));
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.promoCode")).sendKeys("rahulshettyacademy");
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button.promoBtn")).click();
        //explicit wait
        w.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("span.promoInfo")));
        System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.promoInfo")).getText());
    }
    
    public static  void addItems(WebDriver driver,String[] itemsNeeded)
    {
        int j=0;
        List<WebElement> products=driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("h4.product-name"));
        for(int i=0;i<products.size();i++)
        {
            //Brocolli - 1 Kg
            //Brocolli,    1 kg
            String[] name=products.get(i).getText().split("-");
            String formattedName=name[0].trim();
            //format it to get actual vegetable name
            //convert array into array list for easy search
            //  check whether name you extracted is present in arrayList or not-
            List itemsNeededList = Arrays.asList(itemsNeeded);
            if(itemsNeededList.contains(formattedName))
            {
                j++;
                //click on Add to cart
                driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='product-action']/button")).get(i).click();
                if(j==itemsNeeded.length)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you read the error message, it indicates that `C:\chromedriver.exe` is expected to be found but is missing.

Answer (score 0):

```
 System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C://chromedriver.exe");
```

defines that the chrome driver binary is located at `C:\chromedriver.exe`. But the exception says the file does not exists there.

So just download the chrome driver from https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads and move + rename it to  `C:\chromedriver.exe` and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable must exist: C:\chromedriver.exe
```

...implies that the program was unable to find the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59909654/how-does-chrome-driver-interact-with-chrome-browser/59927747#59927747) executable in the specified location.

---

### Solution

You need to take care of a couple of things here as follows:

- Ensure that you have downloaded the exact format of the *ChromeDriver* binary from the [download location](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.39/) pertaining to your underlying OS among:

  - *chromedriver_win32*: For *Windows OS*
  - *chromedriver_mac64*: For *MAC OS X*
  - *chromedriver_linux64*: For *Linux OS*
- Instead of storing the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53727887/what-is-benefit-of-using-chromedriver-over-webdriver-if-we-are-using-only-chrome/53744026#53744026) executable within **`C:\`** drive, keep it within a *directory*, e.g. *`C:\BrowserDrivers\`*. So effectively your line of code will be:

  ```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C://BrowserDrivers//chromedriver.exe");
  ```
- Ensure that *ChromeDriver* binary have executable permission for the **non-administrator**  user.
- Execute your *Test* as a **non-administrator**  user.