# Selenium - Unable to start server with either IPv4 or IPv6. Exiting

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to open chromedriver.exe but I'm given this error message:
*"Unable to start server with either ipv4 or ipv6. Exiting.."*

I tried the following but didn't work:

1. Tried opening the chromedriver using a specific port that is has no process connected to it.
2. Downloaded chromedriver to be the same version of chrome browser.
3. Restarted the machine and try opening the driver again.

Notes:

- The driver starts but rarely. I took the port that it once started using it and tried to open it again using this specific port but it didn't start.
- I tried IE driver as well and the same issue occured.

Error trace log:

```
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17
:03'
System info: host: 'GRKIF-CTXDA034', ip: '10.41.162.52', os.name: 'Windows Serve
r 2012 R2', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_201'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown

Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17
:03'
System info: host: 'GRKIF-CTXDA034', ip: '10.41.162.52', os.name: 'Windows Serve
r 2012 R2', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_201'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown

(03:51:05.534) - Warning: Cannot connect to server to check for updates (Server
returned HTTP response code: 504 for URL: http://10.97.109.210:8081/tacoe/downlo
ads/readme.txt), please connect to office net.
(03:51:16.760) - Info: Default Web Browser: Chrome
(03:51:16.760) - Info: Target (Name:Web, Platform:Web, Type:Chrome, Hub IP:Local
, Default:false) added.
Jan 10, 2022 3:51:16 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities chrome
INFO: Using `new ChromeOptions()` is preferred to `DesiredCapabilities.chrome()`(03:51:16.823) - Info: Chrome config created.
(03:51:16.839) - Info: Chrome config loaded.
(03:51:16.854) - Info: Target Type: Chrome
(03:51:16.870) - Info: ==============================
(03:51:16.870) - Info: Capabilities:
(03:51:16.885) - Info: Capability: acceptSslCerts=true
(03:51:16.901) - Info: Capability: applicationCacheEnabled=true
(03:51:16.901) - Info: Capability: browserConnectionEnabled=true
(03:51:16.917) - Info: Capability: browserName=chrome
(03:51:16.932) - Info: Capability: databaseEnabled=true
(03:51:16.948) - Info: Capability: elementScrollBehavior=1
(03:51:16.948) - Info: Capability: javascriptEnabled=true
(03:51:16.964) - Info: Capability: locationContextEnabled=true
(03:51:16.979) - Info: Capability: nativeEvents=true
(03:51:16.995) - Info: Capability: platform=ANY
(03:51:16.995) - Info: Capability: proxy={​​proxyType=SYSTEM, autodetect=false, ft
pProxy=null, httpProxy=null, noProxy=null, sslProxy=null, socksProxy=null, socks
Version=null, socksUsername=null, socksPassword=null, proxyAutoconfigUrl=null}​​
(03:51:17.010) - Info: Capability: rotatable=false
(03:51:17.026) - Info: Capability: unexpectedAlertBehaviour=ignore
(03:51:17.026) - Info: Capability: unhandledPromptBehavior=ignore
(03:51:17.042) - Info: Capability: version=
(03:51:17.057) - Info: Capability: webStorageEnabled=true
(03:51:17.073) - Info: Capability: webdriver.remote.quietExceptions=false
(03:51:17.089) - Info: ==============================
(03:51:17.089) - Info: Configurations:
(03:51:17.104) - Info: Config: target_path=
(03:51:17.120) - Info: Config: timeout_page=120000
(03:51:17.120) - Info: Config: timeout_find=2000
(03:51:17.135) - Info: Config: timeout_jscript=5000
(03:51:17.151) - Info: Config: timeout_ajax=20000
(03:51:17.167) - Info: Config: wait_for_pageLoad=true
(03:51:17.167) - Info: Config: serverAddress=Local
(03:51:17.182) - Info: Config: auto_select_window=false
(03:51:17.198) - Info: Config: auto_maxmize=false
(03:51:17.198) - Info: Config: mobileEmulation=false
Starting ChromeDriver 96.0.4664.45 (76e4c1bb2ab4671b8beba3444e61c0f17584b2fc-ref
s/branch-heads/4664@{​​#947}​​) on port 14593
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggest
ions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
Unable to start server with either IPv4 or IPv6. Exiting...
Jan 10, 2022 3:51:37 PM org.openqa.selenium.os.OsProcess checkForError
SEVERE: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error:
1 (Exit value: 1)
(03:51:37.246) - Error: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17
:03'
System info: host: 'GRKIF-CTXDA034', ip: '10.41.162.52', os.name: 'Windows Serve
r 2012 R2', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_201'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to s
tart.
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17
:03'
System info: host: 'GRKIF-CTXDA034', ip: '10.41.162.52', os.name: 'Windows Serve
r 2012 R2', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_201'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(D
riverService.java:202)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.
java:188)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(Driv
erCommandExecutor.java:79)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.ja
va:552)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriv
er.java:213)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.jav
a:131)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:181)at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:168)at 
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException: Timed out waitin
g for [http://localhost:14593/status] to be available after 20012 ms
at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java
:100)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(D
riverService.java:197)
... 12 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:205)
at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(S
impleTimeLimiter.java:156)
at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java
:75)
... 13 more
(03:51:37.371) - Error: Browser didn't open.
```

Comment: Update the question with the complete error trace log.

Comment: Let me have a relook

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
Unable to start server with either IPv4 or IPv6. Exiting...
```

...implies that the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59909654/how-does-chrome-driver-interact-with-chrome-browser/59927747#59927747) was unable to initiate/spawn a new *Browsing Context* i.e. *Chrome Browser* session.

Possibly your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53727887/what-is-benefit-of-using-chromedriver-over-webdriver-if-we-are-using-only-chrome/53744026#53744026) version is not getting detected:

```
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v96.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=96.0.4664.45/) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current *chrome=96.0.4664.45* (as per [chrome=96.0.4664.45 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/96.0.4664.45/notes.txt)).