# Starting Selenium Grid with Selenium 4 for C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-grid, remotewebdriver, selenium4

I am having issues running Selenium Grid from Visual Studio from Csharp using Selenium 4. I keep getting the error:

Message:

```
System.InvalidOperationException : Could not start a new session. Could not start a new session. Error while creating session with the driver service. Stopping driver service: Driver server process died prematurely.
Build info: version: '4.1.1', revision: 'e8fcc2cecf'
System info: host: 'ATTPA-1450', ip: '172.26.0.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '11.0.12'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
Build info: version: '4.1.1', revision: 'e8fcc2cecf'
System info: host: 'ATTPA-1450', ip: '172.26.0.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '11.0.12'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
Build info: version: '4.1.1', revision: 'e8fcc2cecf'
System info: host: 'ATTPA-1450', ip: '172.26.0.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '11.0.12'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown (SessionNotCreated)
TearDown : System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Stack Trace:

```
WebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
WebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
WebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
WebDriver.ctor(ICommandExecutor executor, ICapabilities capabilities)
RemoteWebDriver.ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
RemoteWebDriver.ctor(Uri remoteAddress, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
WebDriverFactory.OpenBrowser() line 28
BaseTest.Test_Setup() line 54*
```

Can you tell me what I am missing. I downloaded the .jar file from this location - https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/

I started selenium hub on my local machine here:
[image]

I then registered selenium node here:
[image]

I made sure I can get to grid here:
[image]

Here is my code (I initially used http://localhost:4444/wd/hub) but still got the same error:
[image]

When I change the code to

I get this error

```
_driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), browserOptions);
```

Message:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/session timed out after 60 seconds.
  ----> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException : The operation was canceled.
  ----> System.IO.IOException : Unable to read data from the transport connection: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request..
  ----> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException : The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.
TearDown : System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.*
```

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
System.InvalidOperationException : Could not start a new session. Could not start a new session. Error while creating session with the driver service. Stopping driver service: Driver server process died prematurely.
Build info: version: '4.1.1', revision: 'e8fcc2cecf'
System info: host: 'ATTPA-1450', ip: '172.26.0.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '11.0.12'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

...implies that the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59909654/how-does-chrome-driver-interact-with-chrome-browser/59927747#59927747) was unable to initiate/spawn a new *Browsing Context* i.e. *Chrome Browser* session.

Possibly your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53727887/what-is-benefit-of-using-chromedriver-over-webdriver-if-we-are-using-only-chrome/53744026#53744026) version is not getting detected:

```
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver 97.0.4692.71](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=97.0.4692.71/) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current *chrome=Version 97.0.4692.71* (as per [chrome=97.0.4692.71 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/97.0.4692.71/notes.txt)).