# Cannot construct KeyEvent from non-typeable key only with special characters, using Selenium-chromedriver

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

When I send keys by selenium which contains special characters such as '**@**' I got back this error:

> Cannot construct KeyEvent from non-typeable key

However, with alphabet characters, the function `.send_keys()` works. I would like to send my username to the [Squarespace login page](https://login.squarespace.com/api/1/login/oauth/provider/authorize?client_id=qNgYXXcY8Fa8M&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.squarespace.com%2Fauth%2Foauth%2Fconnect%3FdestinationUrl%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.squarespace.com%252Fauth%252Fprotected-redirect%252Flogin%253Flocation%253Dhttps%25253A%25252F%25252Faccount.squarespace.com&state=1%3A1644844643%3A0eKy%2FD8GD6e%2F33MuxG5Z2kGrfjwWE6iwx1XTRChxvx8%3D&overrideLocale=en-US&options=%7B%22isCloseVisible%22%3Atrue%2C%22isCreateAccountViewActive%22%3Afalse%7D#/) as "foo@email.com". I have tried using Chrome, Safari, Firefox as the webdriver and the same error appears on all cases.

**Replicable code example:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = "https://login.squarespace.com/"
driver.get(url)
email_but = driver.find_element_by_name("email")
email_but.send_keys('foo@email.com')
```

I tried to go around the error by copying into the clipboard and then pasting onto the field:

```
import xerox
username = "foo@email.com"
xerox.copy(username)
email_but = driver.find_element_by_name("email")
email_but.click()
email_but.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'v')
```

But the same error appears.

I am currently using:

- OSX v.12.0.1
- Chromedriver v.98.0.4758.80
- Chrome v.98.0.4758.80
- Safari v.15.1

Answer (score 2):

This error message...

```
Cannot construct KeyEvent from non-typeable key
```

...using [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447) ***v98*** is the result of the following regression:

> [Issue 3999: Executing a sendKeys(Keys.chord()) results in extra symbol character prefixed to inputted text using Chrome / driver 98](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=3999)

while trying to address the **non-BMP** issue:

> [Issue 2269: Impossible to use non-BMP characters (code points above U+FFFF)](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=2269).

However, the CL have been [Revert "WebDriver supports non-BMP characters in SendKeys"](https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/chromium/src/+/3442961) but was blocked due to [Issue 1295243: Regression in ChromeDriver sendKeys](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1295243)

---

### Fix availability

The fix is verified and would be released with ChromeDriver ***v98.0.4758.99*** and ChromeDriver ***v99.0.4844.29***.

---

### Alternative

As an alternative, you can also use [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) *v98.0* with [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53744026/7429447) *v97.0*