# Unable to find an exact match for CDP version 109, so returning the closest version found: a no-op implementation using Selenium 4x ChromeDriver 109

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium4

I am trying to execute a basic Selenium Java program:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.quit();
}
```

With the following configuration:

- Selenium 4.x
- Chrome *Version 109.0.5414.75 (Official Build) (64-bit)* (Win 10)
- ChromeDriver 109.0.5414.25

ChromeDriver:

[image: ChromeDriver_starting]

Chrome and ChromeDriver both being of Version 109.x, though the program executes successfully still I see some *WARNING* messages on the console as follows:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 109.0.5414.25 (771113d280dd3dda2fb422a6c805f0eb2b8ee6ed-refs/branch-heads/5414@{#303}) on port 57273
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Jan 14, 2023 3:10:47 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected upstream dialect: W3C
Jan 14, 2023 3:10:47 AM org.openqa.selenium.devtools.CdpVersionFinder findNearestMatch
WARNING: Unable to find an exact match for CDP version 109, so returning the closest version found: a no-op implementation
Jan 14, 2023 3:10:47 AM org.openqa.selenium.devtools.CdpVersionFinder findNearestMatch
INFO: Unable to find CDP implementation matching 109.
Jan 14, 2023 3:10:47 AM org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver lambda$new$3
WARNING: Unable to find version of CDP to use for . You may need to include a dependency on a specific version of the CDP using something similar to `org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-devtools-v86:4.3.0` where the version ("v86") matches the version of the chromium-based browser you're using and the version number of the artifact is the same as Selenium's.
```

Can someone help me to understand the issue behind the warnings:

```
WARNING: Unable to find an exact match for CDP version 109, so returning the closest version found: a no-op implementation
```

and

```
WARNING: Unable to find version of CDP to use for . You may need to include a dependency on a specific version of the CDP using something similar to `org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-devtools-v86:4.3.0` where the version ("v86") matches the version of the chromium-based browser you're using and the version number of the artifact is the same as Selenium's.
```

Answer (score 5):

This is because the compatible version of '**Selenium Dev-Tools**' is not yet released. The latest '**Selenium Dev-Tools**' version is v108 which is compatible with Chrome version **V108**.

You can refer the below repository for all the **Selenium Dev-Tools** versions:

https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/seleniumhq/selenium/

I checked with **Selenium v4.7.2** with **Chrome Version 109.0.5414.75** and with the **Chromedriver v109.0.5414.74**, got the below same warning:

[image]

Then I downgraded Chrome browser to **v108.0.5359.126**, checked with **Selenium v4.7.2** and **ChromeDriver v108.0.5359.71**, this time didn't get the warning:

[image]

The next **Selenium Dev-Tools** version may be released with the next Selenium upgrade.

You can also install Selenium Dev-Tools separately from Maven respository: https://mvnrepository.com/search?q=Selenium+DevTools+V108

Anyway, this is just a warning.

Answer (score 2):

### CDP

With the availablity of [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) [*v4.0.0.0-alpha-1*](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/trunk/java/CHANGELOG#L647) the basic support for ***CDP*** landed via the "DevTools" interface. Moving ahead, from [*v4.0.0-alpha-4*](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/trunk/java/CHANGELOG#L582)  onwards Chrome Debugging Protocol commands now mirror latest CDP spec.

---

### This usecase

As you were using [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447)/GoogleChrome combo v**109.0**, support for it was added recently in [*Selenium v4.8.0*](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/trunk/java/CHANGELOG#L1):

```
v4.8.0
======
* Supported CDP versions: 85, 107, 108, 109
```

So incase someone tries to use [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53744026/7429447)/GoogleChrome combo v**109.0** with ***Selenium v4.7.2*** or earlier,  Selenium won't be able to find an exact match for CDP version 109 and would return the closest version found i.e. **`108`**

Hence the warning:

> WARNING: Unable to find an exact match for CDP version 109, so returning the closest version found