# How to address SessionNotCreatedException with latest chromedriver.exe?

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

I'm trying to run my selenium test with selenium server standalone but getting this exception even I already update chromedriver.exe to the last version 108

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 99
```

And also running with selenium grid standalone but said

```
Starting ChromeDriver 99.0.4844.51
```

This is the part of the code whenever I get or receiving the error

```
System.setProperty(webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver.exe");
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("start-maximized");
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), options);
```

And currently I was using this version of selenium

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>
```

And in PowerShell already reviewed

> PS C:> .\chromedriver.exe -v

> ChromeDriver 108.0.5359.71 (1e0e3868ee06e91ad636a874420e3ca3ae3756ac-refs/branch-heads/5359@{#1016})

> PS C:>

Answer (score 0):

This log messages...

```
Starting ChromeDriver 99.0.4844.51
.
.
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 99
```

...implies that your framework effectively still uses [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447) *v99.0.4844.51* where as the latest *Google Chrome* version is ***109.0.5414.75***

---

### Solution

Download the matching [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53744026/7429447) from [ChromeDriver-Downloads](https://sites.google.com/chromium.org/driver/downloads?authuser=0) and execute your tests.

Comment: Actually I'm currently I'm utilizing 108 version of ChromeDriver that's the weird thing that in logs appear a different one

Comment: ChromeDriver 108.0.5359.71 (1e0e3868ee06e91ad636a874420e3ca3ae3756ac-refs/branch-heads/5359@{#1016})

Comment: @cagoscra Sounds to be your framework specific issue which needs further investigation. Feel free to raise a new ticket with all the relevant details.

Comment: I don't know what details could be relevant, please ask me some and I'll post them. Really need to figure out what's happening with my project.

Comment: First and foremost your code snippet. Additionally if you are using any project specific settings in your IDE (Eclipse, VS Code)