# Using Selenium with ChromeDriver on Windows:Lock file can not be created! Error code: 5

Tags: python-3.x, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

My script was working fine but suddenly got the chrome driver error. it seems like some file is locked but I couldn't able to find out.

This is the error message that I'm getting:

```
  d = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\Rahul\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
[0306/064432.916:ERROR:process_singleton_win.cc(420)] Lock file can not be created! Error code: 5
[0306/064432.916:ERROR:chrome_browser_main.cc(1424)] Failed to create a ProcessSingleton for your profile directory. This means that running multiple instances would start multiple browser processes rather than opening a new window in the existing process. Aborting now to avoid profile corruption.
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
[0306/064432.916:ERROR:process_singleton_win.cc(420)] Lock file can not be created! Error code: 5
[0306/064432.916:ERROR:chrome_browser_main.cc(1424)] Failed to create a ProcessSingleton for your profile directory. This means that running multiple instances would start multiple browser processes rather than opening a new window in the existing process. Aborting now to avoid profile corruption.
```

...implies that possibly there are some [**Zombie**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process) [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447) instances locking the profile which the current [*ChromeDriver*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53744026/7429447) needs to use. Forcibly stopping Selenium in the middle of an execution tends to leave the zombie processes and associated process locks behind.

---

### Solution

You need to manually browse to the specified profile directory and delete the file named *`lockfile`*. If the OS complains that the file is in use, close all [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) instances by killing all of them.

Comment: undetected Selenium. I tried to find out Lockfile in the specified profile directory but I could not find out. Do you know any particular file where I can get it?