# Where to get Chromedriver version 111 for Brave on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, raspberry-pi, selenium-chromedriver

Good Day:

I'm wanting to run Selenium via the Brave Browser on my Pi4. I'm porting working code from Windos 10. apt-get installs version 109 for the chrome driver BUT Python/Brave is wanting version 111. How do I get Brave/Chromedriver in sync?

I did download the Linix64 bit Chromedriver version, unzip, and copied Chromedriver over top of the existing but it yields a Format error.

Searching for Rasbberry Pi Chromedriver 111 yields no results.

Brave Version 1.49.120 Chromium: 111.0.5563.64 (Official Build) (64 Bit)
Chromium-chromedriver: 109.0.5414.112-rpt2

Answer (score 0):

*Chromium* team per se *Google* doesn't build and publish ***AMR32 (armv7l)*** builds of [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447) anymore. The latest version of *chromedriver-linux32* was released for *`version 2.33`*

---

### Solution

[Raspbian project](https://www.raspbian.org/) have compiled *chromium-chromedriver* version for the ***armhf*** platform and added it to the repo. To download and install the latest available version of the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53744026/7429447) and use together with [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) you need to supply the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install chromium-chromedriver
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The command above is exactly what was used to install Chromedriver and the version installed is 109 not 111. AND when I run the python script, the error message says to get a compatible version. Hence my question about locating version 111 (OR perhaps downgrading BRAVE to 109).

Comment: Here is the message I'm getting: "This version of ChromeDreiver only supports Chrome version 109 Current browser version is 111.0.5563.64 with binary path /usr/bin/brave-browser

Comment: @DanielHempy So the latest compiled ChromeDreiver version being **109** you have to downgrade Chrome.

Comment: That's exactly my question except I'm looking for a downgrade for Brave.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I've found:

Listed all available versions:

```bash
sudo apt list -a brave-browser
```

To install the earliest version from the list:

```
sudo apt-get install brave-browser=1.47.171
```

Where `1.47.171` is the earliest version in the repository as seen in the results of the first command.