# Error while running a script with selenium in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver

While running the script to open browsers facing error

I tried all the possible ways, help me how to resolve this. Also help me in association selenium with eclipse

```
Starting ChromeDriver 114.0.5735.90 (386bc09e8f4f2e025eddae123f36f6263096ae49-refs/branch-heads/5735@{#1052}) on port 23679
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
[1689787194.974][SEVERE]: listen() returned an error: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions. (0x271D)
[1689787194.975][SEVERE]: bind() returned an error: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions. (0x271D)
Unable to start server with either IPv4 or IPv6. Exiting...
Jul 19, 2023 10:50:14 PM org.openqa.selenium.os.OsProcess checkForError
SEVERE: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-6C9U84R', ip: '192.168.174.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '17.0.7'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:202)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:188)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:79)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:181)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:168)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:123)
    at as.Atleastnow.main(Atleastnow.java:10)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for [http://localhost:23679/status] to be available after 20005 ms
    at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:100)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:197)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:204)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:156)
    at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:75)
    ... 10 more
```

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
Starting ChromeDriver 114.0.5735.90 (386bc09e8f4f2e025eddae123f36f6263096ae49-refs/branch-heads/5735@{#1052}) on port 23679
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
[1689787194.974][SEVERE]: listen() returned an error: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions. (0x271D)
[1689787194.975][SEVERE]: bind() returned an error: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions. (0x271D)
Unable to start server with either IPv4 or IPv6. Exiting...
Jul 19, 2023 10:50:14 PM org.openqa.selenium.os.OsProcess checkForError
SEVERE: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-6C9U84R', ip: '192.168.174.1', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '17.0.7'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
```

...implies that *WebDriverException* was raised as the driver server process failed to start.

The most probhable reason is, [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) ***v3.141.59*** is incompatible with recently released [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53744026/7429447) ***v114.0.5735.90***

---

### Solution

Update *Selenium* version to recently released [***Version 4.10.0***](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/) and execute your tests.