# What is the difference between ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(); and WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, interface, webdriver

What is the difference between:

```
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver ();
```

and

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver ();
```

Will I get same output if I use any of these codes in Selenium Java?

I didn't any difference in two codes so will my output also same if I use of these two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

When using:

```
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

The [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447) instance will be only able to invoke and act on the methods implemented by [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53744026/7429447) and supported by [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) only. To act with other browsers we have to specifically create individual objects as below :

- `FirefoxDriver driver =  new FirefoxDriver();`
- `InternetExplorerDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();`

---

### WebDriver Interface

From [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) perspective, the *`WebDriver Interface`* is similar like a agreement which the 3rd party *Browser Vendors* like [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox), [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome), [internet-explorer](/questions/tagged/internet-explorer), [safari](/questions/tagged/safari), etc have to adhere and implement the same. This would in-turn help the end-users to use the exposed APIs to write a common code and implement the functionalities across all the available `Browsers` without any change.

---

### WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

Using *`WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();`* you are creating an instance of the [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48080871/7429447) interface and **casting** it to *ChromeDriver Class*. All the *browser drivers* like [FirefoxDriver](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxDriver.html), [ChromeDriver](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/chrome/ChromeDriver.html), [InternetExplorerDriver](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/ie/InternetExplorerDriver.html), [PhantomJSDriver](http://phantomjs.org/), [SafariDriver](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/safari/SafariDriver.html) etc implemented the [WebDriver](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html) interface (actually the [RemoteWebDriver](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebDriver.html) class implements *WebDriver Interface* and the *Browser Drivers* extends *RemoteWebDriver*). So if we use `WebDriver driver`, then we can use the already initialized *driver* (as common object variable) for all browsers we want to automate e.g. Mozilla, Chrome, InternetExplorer, PhantomJS, Safari.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver = new SafariDriver();
```

Comment: So If I use *WebDriver driver* no need to write "FirefoxDriver" before "driver"?

Answer (score 0):

The correct driver initialisation is the second one. Use this:

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver ();
```

Comment: I am asking difference in outputs. Do you think first code is wrong?

Comment: The first one will work fine, but only for chrome testing. When you use first one, that means you are creating instance of ChromeDriver. As per the java concept if you create an object using New keyword it will initiate constructor of that class. We have object of ChromeDriver class. 
So to balance that out you should create object of browser driver by referencing it to WebDriver instance like the second option. With the second option you're creating an instance of the WebDriver interface and casting it to browser driver class, which makes more sense:=)