# Python, Selenium: How to specify which sites can load images?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, chrome-options

In Selenium chromdriver, we can disable images in this way:

```
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images": 2}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

But this method disables images on all sites. In Google Chrome, you can separately specify a list of sites to which images can be loaded.

Is it possible to do this with Selenium?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**No**, you won't be able to configure *ChromeOptions* differently per site unless you reinitialize [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447) and [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome)

When you configure an instance of a *ChromeDriver* using `ChromeOptions()` in the process of initiating a new *Chrome Browsing Session* the configuration gets **baked** into the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53744026/7429447) service instance and will persist till the lifetime of the [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48080871/7429447) being **uneditable**. So you can't add any further *ChromeOptions* to the [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70974827/7429447) instance which is currently in execution.

Even if you are able to extract the *ChromeDriver* and *ChromeSession* attributes e.g. *Session ID*, *Cookies*, *UserAgent* and other session attributes from the already initiated *ChromeDriver* and *Chrome Browsing Session* still you won't be able to change the set of attributes of the *ChromeDriver*.

A cleaner way would be to call **`driver.quit()`** within `tearDown(){}` method to **close** and **destroy** the current *ChromeDriver* and *Chrome Browser* instances gracefully and then span a new set of *ChromeDriver* and *Chrome Browser* instance with the new set of configurations.

---

### tl; dr

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Change ChromeOptions in an existing webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53025100/7429447)