# Equivalent of time.sleep() in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I realize this is a relatively simple question but I haven't found the answer yet.

I'm using `driver.get()` in a for loop that iterates through some urls.  To help avoid my IP address getting blocked, I've implemented `time.sleep(5)` before the `driver.get statement` in the for loop.

Basically, I just want a wait period to make my scraping seem more natural.

I think `time.sleep` may be causing page crashes.  What is the equivalent of `time.sleep` in selenium?  From what I understand, `implicitly_wait` just sets the amount of time before throwing an exception, but I'm not sure that's what I want here?  I want a specific amount of time for the driver to wait.

Comment: `time. sleep()` is from `Python` however Selenium does have the `.pause` method and that is for web element interaction load time. However, I don't think that you need `.pause` here. Your question is not really clear to me. Did you intend to ask why the page crashes during Selenium code execution?

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 2):

### time.sleep()

The [sleep()](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/time/sleep) function is from the [time](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/time) module which suspends execution of the current thread for a given number of seconds.

Now, [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48080871/7429447) being a out-of-process library which instructs the browser what to perform and at the same time the web browser being asynchronous in nature, WebDriver can't track the active, real-time state of the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp). This gives rise to some intermittent issues that arise from usage of *Selenium* and *WebDriver* those are subjected to race conditions that occur between the browser and the user’s instructions.

As of now [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) doesn't have any identical method to `time.sleep()`, however there are two equavalent methods at your disposal and can be used as per the prevailing condition of your automated tests.

- [Implicit wait](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/#implicit-wait): In this case, WebDriver polls the DOM for a certain duration when trying to find any element. This can be useful when certain elements on the webpage are not available immediately and need some time to load.

  ```
  def implicitly_wait(self, time_to_wait) -> None:
      """
      Sets a sticky timeout to implicitly wait for an element to be found,
         or a command to complete. This method only needs to be called one
         time per session. To set the timeout for calls to
         execute_async_script, see set_script_timeout.

      :Args:
       - time_to_wait: Amount of time to wait (in seconds)

      :Usage:
          ::

              driver.implicitly_wait(30)
    """
    self.execute(Command.SET_TIMEOUTS, {
        'implicit': int(float(time_to_wait) * 1000)})
  ```
- [Explicit wait](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/#explicit-wait): This type of wait allows your code to halt program execution, or freeze the thread, until the condition you pass it resolves. As an example:

  - [*presence_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57313803/7429447)
  - [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447)
  - [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447)

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific method in Selenium for hardcoded pauses like a `time.sleep()` general Python method.
As you mentioned there is an `implicitly_wait` and Expected Conditions explicit `WebDriverWait` waits but both these are NOT a hardcoded pauses.
Both the `implicitly_wait` `WebDriverWait` are used for setting the timeout - how long time to poll for some element presence or condition, so if that condition is fulfilled or the element is presented the program flow will immediately continue to the next code line.
So, if you want to put a pause you have to use some general Python method that will suspend the program / thread run like the `time.sleep()`.

Comment: Not sure if you are aware of `pause` method in selenium, it is equivalent to `time.sleep()` that is available in Python.

Comment: I indeed not familiar with such Selenium method. Maybe because I mostly use Selenium with Java? So, you think I should remove this answer @cruisepandey?

Comment: No that's not I meant. You can keep the answer, if OP is fine with the solution I don't have any issue. In Java also when you create an actions class object, you'd see .pause method.

Comment: OK, I thought about Selenium itself :)