# Getting the IP address used by a proxy

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, proxy

I have the following code:

```
API_KEY = 'YOUR_API_KEY'

proxy_options = {
    'proxy': {
        'http': f'http://scraperapi:{API_KEY}@proxy-server.scraperapi.com:8001',
        'https': f'http://scraperapi:{API_KEY}@proxy-server.scraperapi.com:8001',
        'no_proxy': 'localhost,127.0.0.1'
    }
}

driver = webdriver.Chrome(seleniumwire_options=proxy_options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
driver.get(url)

# Rest of the code
```

How can I print the IP every time `driver.get(url)` is runned?

Comment: Use `print(driver.current_url)`

Answer (score 0):

A simpler approach would be to wrapup the initialization of [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48080871/7429447) initiated [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) *Browsing Context* within a for loop as follows:

```
API_KEY = 'YOUR_API_KEY'

proxy_options = {
    'proxy': {
    'http': f'http://scraperapi:{API_KEY}@proxy-server.scraperapi.com:8001',
    'https': f'http://scraperapi:{API_KEY}@proxy-server.scraperapi.com:8001',
    'no_proxy': 'localhost,127.0.0.1'
    }
}

my_url_list = ['https://www.google.com/', 'https://stackoverflow.com/']

for url in my_url_list:
    try:
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(seleniumwire_options=proxy_options)
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
        driver.get(url)
        print(driver.current_url)
    except:
        continue
```

Comment: But this prints the current URL, I would need the current IP.

Comment: Were does the IP address shows up? In the url?

Comment: It prints `https://www.google.com/` and `https://stackoverflow.com/`.

Comment: Yes, we are printing the `current_url`, hence `https://www.google.com/` and `https://stackoverflow.com/` is printed. Where does the **IP address** gets reflected which you want to print?

Comment: I see that the Google page is open in a different language, so I guess the request is made via a different IP. But I didn't understand how to see it.

Comment: @LJG If you can update me where _`IP address`_ information is getting reflected, I can suggest you the way to extract the required info.

Comment: I can't understand what you mean, sorry. I thought there was a method to print the IP address used by the proxy in the Python console.

Comment: I solved using `'https://api.ipify.org/?format=json'` twice as URL.