# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable must exist error using Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, geckodriver

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable must exist
```

Code trials:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Hello {
                
    public static void main(String[] args) {            
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "‪C:\\Users\\91831\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\eclipse-workspace\\geckodriver.exe");
        System.out.println("Hello");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http:\\www.amazon.in");
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable must exist
```

...implies that the [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48080871/7429447) executable doesn't exists at the mentioned location.

---

You have mentioned:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "‪C:\\Users\\91831\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\eclipse-workspace\\geckodriver.exe");
```

As you are using [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) operating system, ensure that you have downloaded [GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45331403/7429447) with ***`.zip`*** extension  from the [release location](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases), unzipped the executable binary and placed ***geckodriver.exe*** within *`‪C:\\Users\\91831\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\eclipse-workspace`* sub-directory.