# org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for http://localhost:56561/shutdown to become unavailable after 3005 ms

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium4

Timed out waiting for driver server to shutdown.

```
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for http://localhost:56561/shutdown to become unavailable after 3005 ms
```

I have no problems with my code. When I run one by one, it doesn't show error. But when I run many test some show error. This problem happens when I run many tests and I use `driver.quit()`.

I know when We use `driver.quit()` Selenium has 3 seconds to kill the browser, if it doesn't happen this problem can happen.

I'm using Macbook pro, so I don't have problem with perform

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to shutdown.
Build info: version: '4.2.2', revision: '683ccb65d6'
System info: host: 'inote689', ip: '2804:14d:5cd4:6383:0:0:0:8b6%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'aarch64', os.version: '12.4', java.version: '18.0.1.1'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [2058629088b94f1aa0e3d0c8c011bd64, quit {}]
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 103.0.5060.134, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 103.0.5060.53 (a1711811edd7..., userDataDir: /var/folders/2v/35htd_0j4yz...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:60202}, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platformName: MAC, proxy: Proxy(), se:cdp: ws://localhost:60202/devtoo..., se:cdpVersion: 103.0.5060.134, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: 2058629088b94f1aa0e3d0c8c011bd64
```

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to shutdown.
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for http://localhost:56561/shutdown to become unavailable after 3005 ms
```

...implies that when you invoke `driver.quit()` for local executions a call gets triggered to *`/shutdown`* end-point with a timeout of ***3 seconds***. The [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48080871/7429447) implementation would expect that a server would be able to kill and cleanup the session itself within a timespan of ***3 seconds*** after which the process represented by the server component is also destroyed.

As [Krishnan Mahadevan](https://groups.google.com/g/selenium-users/c/6L_ixpY-2Fw/m/c8mOcdjKAwAJ?pli=1) points out, in this usecase it looks like the server components are taking longer than ***3 seconds*** to terminate themselves. That explains the exception you are seeing. The side effect of this is that you may see orphaned server component processes still running.

Not sure if this issue have to anythin with the item in [Selenium `v4.0.0-rc-1` changelist](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/036ee7f6aec797f5fe4608d2f7673e59d7f548b5/java/CHANGELOG#L229):

> Sessions are now stopped when the Node is gracefully shutdown.

An immediate recomedation woould be to upgrade to [*Selenium **Version 4.3.0***](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/)