# Geckodriver get error message NS_BINDING_ABORTED when calling webdriver.Firefox

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I'm really struggling with the geckodriver. When running the code below I get the error message "SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Error: NS_BINDING_ABORTED". The most recent call is the line where I call "driver = webdriver.Firefox(...)"

I've looked "everywhere" - would really appreciate any help!

```
import parameters
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver

option = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
option.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
option.add_argument("start-maximized")
option.binary_location=r'C:/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe'

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:/Users/MO/geckodriver.exe', options=option)
driver.maximize_window()
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the argument `--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled`:

```
option.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
```

It was designed for [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48080871/7429447) / [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) combo but not for [GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45331403/7429447) / [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox) combo.

Comment: I tried to remove the argument, however I still get the same error message in the same line