# Failed to Load application error when testing the application using selenium-webdriver and spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Pom.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.8</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.ksupwlt</groupId>
    <artifactId>stepcounttracker</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>stepcounttracker</name>
    <description>KSU Patient Weight Loss Tracker</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <selenium.version>3.141.59</selenium.version>
        <webdrivermanager.version>4.3.1</webdrivermanager.version>
        <testng.version>7.7.1</testng.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.14 </version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>${webdrivermanager.version}</version>

        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>${testng.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7.8</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>com.ea.SpringBasic.SpringTestNGTest</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Webdriver Library

```
import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class WebDriverLibrary {

    @Bean
    public WebDriver getChromeDriver(){
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        return new ChromeDriver();
    }

}
```

Main Page

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class MainPage {
    @Autowired
    private LandingPage landingPage;

    @Autowired
    private LoginPage loginPage;

    @Autowired
    private SignUpPage signUpPage;

    @Autowired
    private QuestionnairePage questionnairePage;

    @Autowired
    private UserProfilePage userProfilePage;

    @Value("${app.url}")
    private String appUrl;

    @Value("chrome")
    private String browser;

    @Autowired
    private WebDriver webDriver;

    public void PerformLogin(){
        webDriver.navigate().to(appUrl);
        System.out.println(appUrl);
        landingPage.ClickLetStart();
        loginPage.ClickLogin();
    }
```

Application test context

```
@SpringBootTest
class StepcounttrackerApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private MainPage mainPage;



    @Test
    void contextLoads() {

        mainPage.PerformLogin();
        mainPage.EditUserProfile();
        mainPage.PerformSignup();
        mainPage.SubmitQuestion();
    }

}
```

---

I am getting the following error

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mainPage': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'webDriver'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'getChromeDriver' defined in class path resource [com/ksupwlt/stepcounttracker/libraries/WebDriverLibrary.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver]: Factory method 'getChromeDriver' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: Companion
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:660)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:731)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:136)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:141)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:90)
    ... 71 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same issue. Newest version which is works for me:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.0</version>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the *Reference* to the [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48080871/7429447) *Interface*. You need to:

```
import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class WebDriverLibrary {

    @Bean
    public WebDriver getChromeDriver(){
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
        return webDriver;
    }

}
```

Comment: I am getting the same error. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

 at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)

Comment: Updated the answer. Retest and let me know the status.

Comment: still the same error

Comment: I tried the selenium 4.1.2 version. it resolved the error