# Ensure browser is closed even if script is forced exited

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am trying to close browser even if the script is not exited normally. I have tried few methods which I found on internet but failed to do so. First was to use try/except and finally. I implemented it but if does not works if the script execution is forcefully stopped.
I have reproduced the code I have. It is not closing the browser on force exit if using chrome. Firefox is closing without any problem. The code is divided in two files (scraper.py, initialize.py)

*scraper.py*

```
try:
    from .initialize import Init
except:
    from initialize import Init
import time

URL = "https://web.whatsapp.com/"
def main(driver):
     # do parsing and other stuff
     driver.get(URL)
     time.sleep(15)

def get_driver(browser, headless):
    # calling start drivers method of init class from initialize file
    return Init(method='profile',write_directory='output/',selenium_wire=True,undetected_chromedriver=True,old_profile_using=False).start_driver(browser=browser, url=URL, headless=headless, refresh=True)
 

try:
    driver = get_driver("firefox" , False)
    main(driver)
    # get_driver returns driver.
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error: {e}")
finally:
        try:
            driver.quit()
        except NameError:
            pass
```

*initialize.py*

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import shutil, os, sys, getpass, browser_cookie3, json, traceback
from time import sleep
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
from webdriver_manager import utils

"""def drivers():
    driver_installation = ChromeDriverManager().install()
    service = Service(driver_installation)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
    return driver

class Init:
    def __init__(self, browser):
        self.browser = browser
    def get_driver(self): #for sake of simplicity this is the get_driver function
        driver = drivers()
        return driver"""

class Init:
    basename = os.path.basename(sys.argv[0]).split(".")[0]  
    homedir  = os.path.join("C:\\ProgramData", basename, getpass.getuser())
    #WRITE_DIRECTORY = 'output_files'
    #WRITE_DIRECTORY = f'{homedir}\output_files/'
    WRITE_DIRECTORY = os.path.join(homedir,'output_files')

    def __init__(self, method, write_directory=WRITE_DIRECTORY, selenium_wire=False,
                 undetected_chromedriver=False, old_profile_using=False):
        self.method = method
        self.write_directory = write_directory
        self.selenium_wire = selenium_wire
        self.undetected_chromedriver = undetected_chromedriver
        self.old_profile_using = old_profile_using

        if not any((self.selenium_wire, self.undetected_chromedriver)):
            raise Exception("Specify at least one driver")
        if method not in ['profile', 'cookies']:
            raise Exception(f"Unexpected method {method=}")

    @staticmethod
    def find_path_to_browser_profile(browser):
        """Getting path to firefox or chrome default profile"""
        if sys.platform == 'win32':
            browser_path = {
                'chrome': os.path.join(
                    os.environ.get('LOCALAPPDATA'), 'Google', 'Chrome', 'User Data'),
                "firefox": os.path.join(
                    os.environ.get('APPDATA'), 'Mozilla', 'Firefox')
            }
        else:
            browser_path = {
                'chrome': os.path.expanduser('~/.config/google-chrome'),
                "firefox": os.path.expanduser('~/.mozilla/firefox')
            }
        path_to_profiles = browser_path[browser]

        print(f'{path_to_profiles=}')
        if os.path.exists(path_to_profiles):
            if browser == 'firefox':
                return browser_cookie3.Firefox.get_default_profile(path_to_profiles)
            if browser == 'chrome':
                return path_to_profiles
        else:
            print(f"{browser} profile - not found")

    def _remove_old_db(self, path_to_browser_profile, browser):

        if browser == 'firefox':
            path_to_browser_profile = os.path.join(path_to_browser_profile, 'storage', 'default')
            folder_list = [i for i in
                           os.listdir(path_to_browser_profile) if 'to-do.live' in i]
            if folder_list:
                path_to_folder = os.path.join(path_to_browser_profile, folder_list[0], 'idb')
                try:
                    shutil.rmtree(path_to_folder)
                    print('removed')
                    return
                except:
                    sleep(2)
                    pass

        elif browser == 'chrome':
            path_to_browser_profile = os.path.join(path_to_browser_profile, 'Default', 'IndexedDB')
        else:
            raise Exception('browser not supported')
        print(path_to_browser_profile)
        folder_list = [i for i in
                       os.listdir(path_to_browser_profile) if 'to-do.live' in i]
        if folder_list:
            print(folder_list[0])
            path_to_folder = os.path.join(path_to_browser_profile, folder_list[0])
            shutil.rmtree(path_to_folder)
            print('removed')

    def init_driver(self, browser, path_to_profile=None, headless=False, remove_old_session=False):
        """Initialize webdriver"""
        print(f"Initialize webdriver for {browser}")
        if self.selenium_wire and self.undetected_chromedriver:
            from seleniumwire.undetected_chromedriver.v2 import Chrome, ChromeOptions # working
        elif self.selenium_wire:
            from seleniumwire.webdriver import Chrome, ChromeOptions # not working
        else:
            from undetected_chromedriver import Chrome, ChromeOptions

        if self.method == 'profile':
            path_to_profile = self.copy_profile(browser)
            if remove_old_session:
                self._remove_old_db(path_to_profile, browser)

        if 'firefox' in browser:
            wdm_path = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), ".wdm", "drivers.json")
            print(wdm_path)
            with open(wdm_path, "r") as f:
                driver_logs = json.load(f)
            gecko_drivers = {}
            g_count = 0
            for drivers, val in driver_logs.items():
                if "geckodriver" in drivers:
                    g_count += 1
                    gecko_drivers[drivers] = val
            firefox_options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
            # firefox_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
            if self.method == 'profile':
                path_to_firefox_profile = path_to_profile
                profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile(path_to_firefox_profile)
                profile.accept_untrusted_certs = True
                profile.set_preference("dom.webdriver.enabled", False)
                profile.set_preference('useAutomationExtension', False)
                profile.set_preference("security.mixed_content.block_active_content", False)
                profile.update_preferences()
                firefox_options.set_preference("general.useragent.override", 'user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0')
                #firefox_options.add_argument(
                #    'user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0')
                if headless:
                    firefox_options.add_argument("--headless")
                firefox_options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
                firefox_options.add_argument("--width=1400")
                firefox_options.add_argument("--height=1000")
                try:
                    driver_installation = GeckoDriverManager().install()
                except Exception as e:
                    c = 1
                    if "rate limit" in str(e):
                        for i in gecko_drivers.values():
                            if c==g_count:
                                driver_installation = i["binary_path"]
                                break
                            c +=1
                service = Service(driver_installation)
                if sys.platform == 'win32':
                    from subprocess import CREATE_NO_WINDOW
                    service.creationflags = CREATE_NO_WINDOW

                driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=firefox_options, firefox_profile=profile,
                                           service=service)
                driver.implicitly_wait(10)
            else:
                firefox_options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
                firefox_options.add_argument('--incognito')
                firefox_options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
                firefox_options.add_argument(
                    'user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0')
                firefox_options.add_argument("--mute-audio")
                if headless:
                    firefox_options.add_argument("--headless")
                try:
                    driver_installation = GeckoDriverManager().install()
                except Exception as e:
                    if "rate limit" in str(e):
                        c = 1
                        for i in gecko_drivers.values():
                            if c==g_count:
                                driver_installation = i["binary_path"]
                            c +=1

                service = Service(driver_installation)
                if sys.platform == 'win32':
                    from subprocess import CREATE_NO_WINDOW
                    service.creationflags = CREATE_NO_WINDOW
                driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=firefox_options, executable_path=driver_installation,
                                           service=service)
            return driver
        elif 'chrome' in browser:
            chrome_options = ChromeOptions()
            if self.method == 'profile':
                chrome_options.add_argument('--no-first-run --no-service-autorun --password-store=basic')
                chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
                # chrome_options.user_data_dir = path_to_profile
                chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1400,1000")
                chrome_options.add_argument(
                    'user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.69 Safari/537.36')
                if sys.platform == 'linux':
                    chrome_options.binary_location = '/bin/google-chrome'
                if headless:
                    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
                # You cannot use default chromedriver for google services, because it was made by google.
                browser_version = int(utils.get_browser_version_from_os('google-chrome').split('.')[0])
                print(f"{browser_version=}")
                driver = Chrome(options=chrome_options, version_main=browser_version, patcher_force_close=True,
                                user_data_dir=path_to_profile)
                driver.implicitly_wait(10)
                return driver
            else:
                chrome_options.add_argument('--incognito')
                chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
                chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
                chrome_options.add_argument("--mute-audio")
                chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1400,1000")
                if headless:
                    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
                chrome_options.add_argument(
                    'user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.127 Safari/537.36')
                driver_installation = ChromeDriverManager().install()
                service = Service(driver_installation)
                if sys.platform == 'win32':
                    from subprocess import CREATE_NO_WINDOW
                    service.creationflags = CREATE_NO_WINDOW
                driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_installation, options=chrome_options, service=service)
            return driver

    def copy_profile(self, browser):
        """Copy browsers profile to /home/{username}/browser_profiles/{browser} directory and returns path to it"""
        path_to_profile = self.find_path_to_browser_profile(browser)
        sys_path_to_copy = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), self.write_directory, browser)
        print(f'copy_profile() initializer: sys_path_to_copy: {sys_path_to_copy}')

        if browser == 'chrome':
            if self.old_profile_using:
                print('Using old profile')
                return sys_path_to_copy
            if not os.path.exists(sys_path_to_copy):
                try:
                    shutil.copytree(path_to_profile, sys_path_to_copy,
                                    symlinks=True, ignore_dangling_symlinks=True, dirs_exist_ok=True)
                except:
                    pass
                print(f'{browser} profile copied from {path_to_profile} to  {sys_path_to_copy}')
            if sys.platform == 'win32':
                 try:  
                    shutil.copytree(os.path.join(sys_path_to_copy,'Default','Network'), os.path.join(sys_path_to_copy,'Default'),dirs_exist_ok=True)
                 except:
                    pass
            return sys_path_to_copy
        elif browser == 'firefox':
            firefox_dir = path_to_profile.split('/')[-1]
            if self.old_profile_using:
                print('Using old profile')
                return os.path.join(sys_path_to_copy, firefox_dir)
            if not os.path.exists(sys_path_to_copy):
                try:
                    shutil.copytree(path_to_profile, os.path.join(sys_path_to_copy, firefox_dir),
                                    ignore_dangling_symlinks=True)
                except:
                    pass
                print(
                    f'{browser} profile copied from {path_to_profile} to  {sys_path_to_copy}/{firefox_dir}')
            return os.path.join(sys_path_to_copy, firefox_dir)


    def start_driver(self, url, browser, headless, refresh=True, remove_old_session=False):
        """Prepering folders and init webdriver"""

        self.create_folders(self.write_directory)
        if self.method == "profile":
            path_to_profile = f'{self.write_directory}{browser}'
            if not self.old_profile_using:
                self.remove_profile_folder(path_to_profile)

        driver = self.init_driver(browser, headless=headless, remove_old_session=remove_old_session)
        try:
            sleep(3)
            driver.get(url)
            sleep(5)
            if refresh and "telegram" not in url:
                driver.refresh()
            print(driver.current_url)
            if driver.current_url == "about:blank":
                driver.get(url)
            sleep(5)
            return driver
        except:
            # raise Exception
            print(traceback.format_exc())
            driver.close()
            driver.quit()

    def remove_profile_folder(self, path_to_profile_folder):
        """Removes browser profile folder"""
        print("Removing old profile")
        while os.path.exists(path_to_profile_folder):
            try:
                shutil.rmtree(path_to_profile_folder)
            except Exception as ex:
                print(ex)
                sleep(2)
                pass

    def create_folders(self, folder_path):
        if not os.path.exists(folder_path):
            print(f'initializer() Creating folder for {folder_path}')
            os.makedirs(folder_path)  # Creating folder
        return folder_path
```

**Things I tried**

```
try:
    driver = get_driver(browser)
    # get_driver returns driver.
    main(
        driver,
    )
except:
    print(traceback.format_exc())
finally:
        try:
            driver.quit()
        except NameError:
            pass
```

The other thing I tried was to use atexit

```
import atexit
def get_driver(browser): #for sake of simplicity this is the get_driver function
    driver_installation = ChromeDriverManager().install()
    service = Service(driver_installation)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
    return driver

@atexit.register()
def cleanup():
     driver.close()
     driver.quit()

try:
    driver = get_driver(browser)
    # get_driver returns driver.
    main(
        driver,
    )
except:
    print(traceback.format_exc())
finally:
        try:
            driver.quit()
        except NameError:
            pass
```

Note, I tries the above in my main code not like this. These also work fine in simple script but not in the code I have provided above.
I do not know if I am using it correctly or not.
The browser is closed on force exit if I am executing the script using VS Code debugger but it fails in simple execution.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing a `None` check before attempting to close the driver. Also, `driver.close()` closes a single browser tab and `driver.quit()` closes the browser along with all open tabs. `driver.quit()` alone should take care of your situation.

```
finally:
    if driver:
        driver.quit()
```

Comment: Did you ever try this? Did it work?

Comment: No, it did not worked

Comment: Although, my problem is not solved I have awarded you the bounty. Because I did not know about the if driver: part. It would be great if you can help me.

Comment: I'm willing to help but you've posted WAY too much code... almost 350 lines. Also, we don't have your profile you are trying to copy, etc. I would suggest that you start super simple. Just do a basic driver init, don't copy the profile, etc. and run it. Slowly add pieces back in until it stops working then examine what you just added. If you do that and figure out what you added that started the problem but still can't figure out how to fix it, post a NEW question with a [mcve], new error message, etc. and we'll try to help.

Comment: Thanks, I will do as you suggested. I though noticed that it only does not works with chrome and also works fine when the code is executed using the debugger.

Comment: Interesting... there may be a timing issue somewhere if it's working while debugging.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to ***close*** & ***destroy*** the [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48080871/7429447) instance and the *Web Client* instances gracefully all you need is:

```
driver.quit()
```

You don't need to invoke `driver.close()` before `driver.quit()`

Comment: My problem is that I want to close web browser in case force exit. Even if I remove driver.close() the browser keeps open on force exit of script

Comment: @farhanjatt Ideally `driver.quit()` should close web browser in case force exit as well and it's quite proven.

Comment: Ok let me try again