# How to locate the search box on Google Home page using Xpath

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver, webdriverwait

I have entered correct from the developer tool xpath still it is not macthing element. How can find the xpath or other locator for google search box.

HTML:

```
<input id="input" type="search" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" role="combobox" ariacontrols="matches" placeholder="Search Google or type a URL" aria-expanded="false" aria-live="polite">
```

Relative Xpath:

```
/html/body/ntp-app/div/div[2]/ntp-realbox/div/input
```

Absolute Xpath:

```
//*[@id="input"]
```

Snapshot A:
[image]

Snapshot B:

[image]

Comment: Pls. attach the code where you call the XPath finder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the snapshot:

[image: snapshot]

You are trying to locate the search box of the default chrome browser page opened manaually, which won't be available within [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) driven [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48080871/7429447) initiated [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) *Browsing Context*

---

Ideally you should access an url. If you access the url *`https://www.google.com/`* you can locate the search box using the following [locator strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Code block:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "q"))).send_keys("BRAJESH KUMAR")
  ```
- Browser snapshot:

[image: BRAJESH KUMAR]

Comment: Yes i was tring to  find the xpath of default chrome browser page opened manaually, which won't be available within Selenium driven ChromeDriver initiated google-chrome Browsing Context. Thanku so much for your kindness support

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may simply look for the **textarea** tag, as seen in the Xpath below.

```
//textarea[@type="search"]
```

[image: google search page screenshot]

Comment: can you give me the direct url of that page?