# Selenium ChromeDriver.get() does not correctly add special characters UTF 8 decoding Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, utf-8

I use selenium version: '3.141.59' to access the content of a page with java, I am using the ChromeDriver to emulate the use of a web browser, my problem occurs when the query url contains special characters --charset=utf -8 since it decodes the character and the result of the web request is not as expected, this is a code example:

```java
System.setProperty(
      "webdriver.chrome.driver",
      "C:\\Program Files\\Controllers\\chromedriver-win64\\chromedriver.exe"
 ); // -> chromedriver version 115.0.5790.102 
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--charset=UTF-8");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.get("úrl/example/with/especial-character/"); // -> url: https://www.Ãºrl/example/with/especial-character/
```

I have tried encoding the url using:

```java
String encoderUrl = URLEncoder.encode("úrl/example/with/especial-character/", "UTF-8");
driver.get(encodeUrl)
```

But this modifies the url which is already encoded, so I'm out of ideas how to solve this, any useful method or library to solve this?

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation platform('org.junit:junit-bom:5.9.1')
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-chrome-driver
    implementation group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-chrome-driver', version: '3.141.59'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-support
    implementation group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-support', version: '3.4.0'
}
```

Comment: *`// -> url: https://www.Ãºrl/example/with/especial-character/`* Forgive me, I don't do Selenium but I take it that's what you see? If so, where - in the console? If so, which console?

Comment: This is how the ChromeDriver handler queries the web page, causing the content it returns to be wrong.

Comment: I believe the get() method has a built-in validator for the URL.  But a URL can only contain standard ASCII characters methinks, so the whole question seems to be based on a URL that can't exist.

Comment: *This is how the ChromeDriver handler queries the web page, causing the content it returns to be wrong.* That doesn't tell me *where* you see that incorrect output

Comment: @g00se When my program runs, the chrome browser opens and displays the content of the page, the url does not take the "ú" character that I mentioned in the example, and replaces it with "Ãº".

Comment: @pcalkins: [https://фрезеровка.москва/](https://фрезеровка.москва/)

Comment: *When my program runs, the chrome browser opens and displays...* OK, so I understand, then, the answer to my question is "the address bar" (?)

Comment: @pcalkins I have run the code in debug mode, I put a breakpoint in my driver.get(url) line and before the wrong url is stored I have set the url that contains the character that is altered, continue the program and the site has been successfully loaded with the content, then I doubt that the URL'S must have ASCII characters compulsorily.

Comment: @g00se Exactly, the bar with the url...

Comment: Sorry couldn't help. I thought it just *might* be in the console

Comment: My thoughts on that is not so much special character as "illegal character" ! in the url.  If the character belongs to a specific language script it may be possible to set locale on it and it's official iso charsets but that would be some work to collude the two together into a program coherently. However outside of a working national language script, url characters, and Latin 1 I would say it is illegal!

Answer (score 0):

[Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) ***v3.141.59*** is **old** and **ancient** now.

---

However using [selenium4](/questions/tagged/selenium4) and [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48080871/7429447) ***v4.10.0***, I find the special characters similar just like accessing manually.

URL

```
https://www.Ãºrl/example/with/especial-character/
```

Manual browser snapshot:

[image: manual]

Code block:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.get("https://www.Ãºrl/example/with/especial-character/");
```

Browser snapshot:

[image: SeleniumDriven]

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve this problem, ChromeDriver is not changing my character encoding internally, the url I am using is exporting from an enum class and the IDE I am using (intellij IDEA) is not encoding my files in utf-8, so which when receiving the value in the class the characters of the string are replaced, it was as simple as doing:

```java
     byte[] asciiURL = url.getBytes();
     String utf8URL = new String(asciiURL, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

And with that it is enough.