# Is it possible to open browser with webbrowser.open and somehow take over by selenium?

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I'm wondering if it's possible to use `webbrowser.open()` method, open the browser, get its handler (?), and use it in
`driver = webdriver.Chrome()` command somehow (webdriver is from selenium)?

Is it feasible at all?

I'm using Python.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can Selenium interact with an existing browser session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8344776/can-selenium-interact-with-an-existing-browser-session)

Comment: The post was about switching between selenium browsers. I'm asking if it possible to take from selenium over non-selenium browser.

Comment: You can attach to a debug session, so just launch with command line switch of "chrome.exe --remote-debugging-port=9222"  (use whatever port you like) then you can launch selenium and set it to use the same port.  This is commonly used when attaching a debugger to a site you are developing.  You should be able to add switches when using webbrowser.open().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***No***, `webbrowser.open()` is from another package unrealted to [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447).

To interact with *Selenium* you have to use a *Selenium* driven [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48080871/7429447) initiated *Browsing Context*.

Comment: ok. that answers my question. I tried undetected Selenium but it's also blocked. It was working last week but somehow now it's stuck on 'Verify you are human'... Have no clue what to do...