# extracting links with a specific class with Selenium in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, infinite-scroll, html-content-extraction

I am trying to extract links from a infinite scroll [website](http://seekingalpha.com/market-news/top-news)

It's my code for scrolling down the page

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Program Files     (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('http://seekingalpha.com/market-news/top-news')
for i in range(0,2):
    driver.implicitly_wait(15)
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(20)
```

I aim at extracting specific links from this page. With class = "market_current_title" and HTML like the following :

```
<a class="market_current_title" href="/news/3223955-dow-wraps-best-week-since-2011-s-and-p-strongest-week-since-2014" sasource="titles_mc_top_news" target="_self">Dow wraps up best week since 2011; S&amp;P in strongest week since 2014</a>
```

When I used

```
URL = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('market_current_title')
```

I ended up with the error that says "stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document". Then I tried

```
 URL = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='a']//a[@class='market_current_title']")
```

but it says that there is no such a link !!!
Do you have any idea about solving this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably trying to interact with an element that is already changed (probably elements above your scrolling and off screen). Try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12967541/how-to-avoid-staleelementreferenceexception-in-selenium) for some good options on how to overcome this.

Here's a snippet:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions as EC
import selenium.webdriver.support.ui as ui

# return True if element is visible within 2 seconds, otherwise False
def is_visible(self, locator, timeout=2):
try:
    ui.WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, locator)))
    return True
except TimeoutException:
    return False
```

Comment: Thanks Mashisho, those answers implemented mainly in Java, Java Script and C#. I could't get the same solution in Python .

Comment: That seems very nice, I tried it like : "elements =      wait.until(driver.find_elements_by_class_name('market_current_title'))"  but I got an error that says : " 'list' object is not callable ". Too strange !!!

Comment: I am wondering if each time I scroll down the page and grab the links and scroll down once again and get the new links, in that respect I think I shouldn't face this problem. Do you have any idea how to do that ?

Comment: The "list object.." error is probably because you can't do `wait.until` on a list, do it for each element (and not element*s*), then scroll again and take the new links until you're on the end of the scroll. Use a while loop. BTW, if my answer is helpful you can vote it...

Comment: Thank you Moshisho, of course your answers were very helpful, as I am new to programming, could you give me some hints as a code of how to scroll and take the links each time?  I am doing " for i in range(0,2):
    driver.implicitly_wait(15)
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)" to scroll down , I dont know how to do it one time and get links and then go on .

Comment: I'm not near a PC now but the idea is to use while(scrollingIsPossible) { scroll; addNewLinks; }

Comment: I really appreciate your help, I would be grateful if you could provide me with more details later on, its part of my research which I got stuck into for many days, any help would be a very nice to me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128081/discussion-between-farshidbalan-and-moshisho).