# Can't read value from a drop down list

Tags: webdriver

I select a value from a drop list and need to read the label. I can't get it work. Any help is appreciated.

```
WebElement stSelection = driver.findElement(By.id("ddlGlobalStoreNumber"));
        Select stSelect = new Select(stSelection); // Create a select object from select class for dropdown selection
        stSelect.selectByIndex(16); 
System.out.println(stSelect.getOptions().get(16).getText());
```

This line containing `System.out` raise the error :

> org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid "StaleElementReferenceException" in Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12967541/how-to-avoid-staleelementreferenceexception-in-selenium)