# Cannot access element from "form", which is not in iFrame

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

#### HTML Code

[image: HTML code]

#### Selenium Code snippet used

```
self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=self.__chrome_options, 
executable_path=self.__path_for_browser_driver)
self.driver.implicitly_wait(10) # seconds
self.driver.get(self.__url)
self.driver.find_element_by_id('username').send_keys(self.__username)
self.driver.find_element_by_id ('password').send_keys(self.__password)
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.__login_button_xpath).click()
self.driver.find_element_by_id('ReportBugFormModal_title').send_keys('Test')
```

**Recieved following error --**

selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

Please help me resolve this. Thank you

Comment: Did you try adding an explicit wait for the presence of the element?

Comment: @GPT14 : explicit wait may not work.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12967541/how-to-avoid-staleelementreferenceexception-in-selenium?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Comment: Please give full error message, we need to know which element caused StaleElementReferenceException.   The full message should tell which element.

Comment: I am agree with @yong , Need to know which element is causing

Comment: is test is a text or document

Comment: Use wait() when y try to locate an element. Something like this: 
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'someid')))

Comment: Sorry for not pasting code, will do it soon.
Meantime -- Error is produced on 
self.driver.find_element_by_id('ReportBugFormModal_title').send_keys('Test') 

This element is highlighted in the HTML code snapshot

Comment: Tried with explicit wait, but receiving the same error.