# How to over Stale element reference exception

Tags: selenium-webdriver

When  `driver.findElement(By.id(eachtitle)).click();` is excecuted application is throwing

> stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
>   error.

```
List<WebElement> visits = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class= \"scrollingbutton\"]"));

System.out.println(visits.size());

for(WebElement eachvisit : visits) {            
       String eachtitle = eachvisit.getAttribute("id");
       driver.findElement(By.id(eachtitle)).click();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid "StaleElementReferenceException" in Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12967541/how-to-avoid-staleelementreferenceexception-in-selenium)

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12967541/how-to-avoid-staleelementreferenceexception-in-selenium

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Before asking a question on this forum try to find the solution on your own. The question you have asked is already been answer as point by @VladimirEfimov. Also go through the link for guide line. [how to ask question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Help Center >> Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).