# Cant fix the StaleElementRefereceException @my send_keys

Tags: python, selenium, browser

So I'm pretty new in Python and I tried something for my own, using selenium and firefox. But I got a StaleElementRefereceException when I want to type into a text field in firefox with selenium using `send_key()`

I tried a lot of Solutions like [How to avoid "StaleElementReferenceException" in Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12967541/how-to-avoid-staleelementreferenceexception-in-selenium) but doesn't help me much because mine is not a `click()`, it's a `send_key`.

```
    hshtg = "xyz"

    driver = self.driver
    driver.get(".......")
    #time.sleep(3)

    cmmnt_elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//textarea[@aria-label="Kommentar hinzufügen ..."]')
    cmmnt_elem.click()
    #time.sleep(3)

    cmmnt_elem.send_keys(hshtg)
    #time.sleep(3)
    cmmnt_elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

But, I got those errors.

```
File ".....py", line 45, in comment_photo
cmmnt_elem.send_keys(hshtg)
```

......

```
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: The element 
reference of <textarea class="Ypffh"> is stale; either the element is no longer 
attached to the DOM, it is not in the current frame context, or the document 
has been refreshed
```

tried this too: (cause of this:  [How to avoid "StaleElementReferenceException" in Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12967541/how-to-avoid-staleelementreferenceexception-in-selenium))

```
attempts = 0
while attempts < 20:
try:
cmmnt_elem.send_keys(hshtg)
break
except Exception as e:
attempts+1
```

In case it's helpful, this is the field:[comment field on instagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JT1Ry.png)

Comment: hard to tell without your xpath, but could the xpath to the textarea change based on your click?

Comment: dont thought its important, i added it!

Answer (score 0):

when you `click` the `textarea` the DOM will be modified, so it will give the error, there are two solution to fix it.

- remove `click()` action

  ```
  cmmnt_elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//textarea[@aria-label="Kommentar hinzufügen ..."]')    
  cmmnt_elem.send_keys(hshtg)
  ```
- Re-search the element after click

  ```
  cmmnt_elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//textarea[@aria-label="Kommentar hinzufügen ..."]')
  cmmnt_elem.click()

  cmmnt_elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//textarea[@aria-label="Kommentar hinzufügen ..."]')
  cmmnt_elem.send_keys(hshtg)
  ```