# How to fix Selenium not clearing default text on an input

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I am trying to input an amount in a text field which contains a default string.

HTML of that field:

```
<div class="InputGroup">
    <span class="InputGroup-context">$</span>
    <input autocomplete="off" class="Input InputGroup-input" id="amount" name="amount" type="text" maxlength="12" value="0.00">
</div>
```

When trying to input text to the field, instead of replacing the default text, it appends it to it.

I have tried to use `amount.clear()` (amount is what I am calling the element) but after running that and sending the keys it throws the below exception:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

As you will see from my current code, I am also trying to double click the default text but that doesn't help.

This is my code at the moment:

```
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(amount).click(amount).click(amount).perform()
amount.send_keys(Keys.BACKSPACE)
amount.send_keys('100')
```

Which results in an input field of 0.00100 when I'm expecting 100.

Comment: If what has already been suggested does not work, you can always send `keys.BACKSPACE` to clear the textbox.

Comment: Do you understand what a `StaleElementReferenceException` is and what causes it?

Comment: check this link. It might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12967541/how-to-avoid-staleelementreferenceexception-in-selenium

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some JS based webs apps may not clear the input fields properly.

You can try using Actions class to click and clear a field fully. For example:

```
elem = driver.findElement(By.id("amount"))
actions.move_to_element(elem).click().build().perform()
actions.send_keys(Keys.BACKSPACE)
       .send_keys(Keys.BACKSPACE)
       .send_keys(Keys.BACKSPACE)
       .send_keys(Keys.BACKSPACE).build().perform()
```

Comment: I feel like an idiot now. Sending backspace 4 times worked :facepalm: