# StaleElementReferenceException error on Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Can you please help solve this problem?

When I run this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException

class ActionsMy():
def test(self):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.get("https://demoqa.com/")
    driver.implicitly_wait(3)

    action = ActionChains(driver)

    # Sortable
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[contains(text(),'Sortable')]").click()
    item1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[contains(text(),'Item 1')]")
    action.drag_and_drop_by_offset(item1, 0, 150).perform()
    time.sleep(1)

    # Resizable
    driver.find_element_by_link_text("Resizable").click()
    resizableElement = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
            "//div[@class='ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se']")
    action.drag_and_drop_by_offset(resizableElement, 200, 200).perform()

 dd = ActionsMy()
 dd.test()
```

I get this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

My research showed this problem related to the fact that the element is no longer in the DOM, or it changed.

I have used this solution:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException

class ActionsMy():
def test(self):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.get("https://demoqa.com/")
    driver.implicitly_wait(3)

    action = ActionChains(driver)

    # Sortable
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[contains(text(),'Sortable')]").click()
    item1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[contains(text(),'Item 1')]")
    action.drag_and_drop_by_offset(item1, 0, 150).perform()
    time.sleep(1)

    # Resizable
    driver.find_element_by_link_text("Resizable").click()
    try:
        resizableElement = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
            "//div[@class='ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se']")
    except StaleElementReferenceException:
        action.drag_and_drop_by_offset(resizableElement, 200, 200).perform()


 dd = ActionsMy()
 dd.test()
```

In this case, there are no errors, but the operation is not performed.

I have also used WebDriverWait, but it did not help either.

Comment: Maybe a retry logic can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12967541/how-to-avoid-staleelementreferenceexception-in-selenium

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in `ActionChains`, it retains all the previous actions, including the `drag_and_drop_by_offset` with `item1` so when `perform()` is called it tries to do this action again, but `item1` is stale.

There is `reset_actions()` function to clear those actions, but it doesn't work. There is [a bug report](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/6837) that indicates it will be fixed in Selenium 4.

In the meantime, create new `ActionChains` instance and use it

```
resizable_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se']")
action = ActionChains(driver)
action.drag_and_drop_by_offset(resizable_element, 200, 200).perform()
```