# Python Selenium - I can't run the while loop

Tags: python, selenium, loops, while-loop

I just started python. I want to write a loop containing bot using Selenium.
I want to login to a site. I send my number and password. The page refreshes when there is density on the server. Number and password sections are being cleaned.
I want it to try to login with the same number and password until I log in to the system.
If I enter text in the number section, the loop works, but I need to enter a number.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("https://www.*****.com")
time.sleep(1)

loginbutton = browser.find_element_by_name('login')
no = browser.find_element_by_name('no')
password = browser.find_element_by_name('pass')

while True:
    no.send_keys("160210051")
    password.send_keys("example")
    time.sleep(1)

    loginbutton.click()
    no.clear()
    password.clear()
    continue
```

[python shell, error descripton](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aH2oj.png)

Comment: Your problem is that you cannot enter a number?

Comment: @MatthewGaiser my problem is no.sendkeys does not send my number when the loop returns.

Comment: stale element exception is your problem, please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12967541/how-to-avoid-staleelementreferenceexception-in-selenium

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid "StaleElementReferenceException" in Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12967541/how-to-avoid-staleelementreferenceexception-in-selenium)

Comment: @MrCas I examined, I tried, but there is no change.

Comment: could you update your question with what exactly you have tried (code)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found finding elements in the while loop and it worked.
The elements in the past are deleted after the page is refreshed.
Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2):

**Add a sleep in the while loop**

Clicking login likely changes the page so that the number and password fields no longer exist. You need to have the `while` pause for a period of time between attempts.

Comment: I add time.sleep(3) before the continue line, but again I get the same error.

Comment: and the name of the fields does not change. still login, no and pass.