# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text', but it works if I don't put .text

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I tried to make an selenium app that scrapes the product name & price from a website, and send it to discord as a webhook.
The error I get is in title.

```
product = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="details"]/h1""")
```

```
embed.add_field(name='Product:', value=str(product).text, inline=False)
```

Thats the line where I am getting the error. ^
But for example if I don't put .text it works on discord, but it doesn't give it as text and it shows like:

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="239269ee47dcdd86ba8f2ebb717ec15a", element="77b2212a-ccd4-4e5c-9a96-f0a931097a2d")>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `.text` call should be on `product`, not your `str()` call, i.e.

```py
embed.add_field(name='Product:', value=product.text, inline=False)
```

Comment: Yes, it is. That function call should be removed.

Comment: I am getting this error now, ``` selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.149)```

Comment: According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12967541/how-to-avoid-staleelementreferenceexception-in-selenium) it can happen if a DOM operation is causing it to be inaccessible. Try attempting it a couple of times as suggested in the post.