# Stale element just after Find

Tags: java, selenium, grails, groovy, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using ChromeDriver in Groovy, for clarification.

I know that you usually can get a Stale Element Exception if you save an element, the page changes and then you try to access it.
But my problem is that I sometimes at random get that error when i literraly just obtained it.

My code looks something like this:

```
def elem = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(xpath)))
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", elem)
elem.click()
```

And it's on the elem.click() that I get the exception, which makes no sense to me.

Comment: the DOM is either still updating, or it's updating after the scroll.  Chances are you don't need that scroll.  The click method will automatically scroll into view.  You can try/catch the click call if needed... if stale element exception is caught, re-get the element.  (OR just use a sleep of a set amount of time after scroll, or before you get the element, depending on what's causing the stale element.)

Comment: I added the scroll 'cause it helped me prevent some other exception, but it's probably a different issue altogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several technologies to implement web pages. In some such technologies web elements are appearing and then re-built so that Selenium detects those elements as visible/clickable but the elements are immediately re-built so the initial reference becomes stale.
On of the simplest workarounds to work on such pages with Selenium is to use loops of `try-catch` like the below:

```java
public boolean retryingFindClick(String xpath) {
    int attempts = 0;
    while(attempts < 5) {
        try {
            def elem = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(xpath)))
            ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", elem)
            elem.click()
            return true;
        } catch(StaleElementException e) {
        }
        attempts++;
    }
    return false;
}
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12967541/how-to-avoid-staleelementreferenceexception-in-selenium) for more details