# Jmeter/Selenium "stale element reference exception error

Tags: selenium, testing, jmeter

I have 10 threads on Jmeter all going into the same website but each thread has different accounts. I keep getting the Stale Element Reference Exception error on 1-3 threads per each test. The weird thing is that the threads that fail are different each time I run a test, and they all have the exact same path/code (besides the login credentials). What can I do to fix it?

When the a thread fails, it says "This site can't be reached" "examplewebsite.com took too long to respond" in the UI

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MpK4K.jpg)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12967541/how-to-avoid-staleelementreferenceexception-in-selenium and some of the answers such as  https://stackoverflow.com/a/12967602/7058266

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [Stale element reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/WebDriver/Errors/StaleElementReference) page:

> The stale element reference error is a WebDriver error that occurs because the referenced web element is **no longer attached to the DOM.**

So it means that you're trying to interact with the element which no longer exists.

Given `This site can't be reached` error it might be the case your application is overloaded or has another problem preventing proper displaying/rendering controls

You could try [taking a screenshot](https://www.baeldung.com/java-selenium-screenshots) in case of failure and/or printing the page source to [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging), this way you will have more information regarding what's going on when the page cannot be opened or element cannot be found/interacted with.

Example code:

```
try
{
   WDS.browser.get('examplewebsite.com')
   wait.until(conditions.presenceOfElementLocated(pkg.By.linkText('some-link')))
}
catch (err)
{
   WDS.log.error(err.message)
   var screenshot = WDS.browser.getScreenshotAs(pkg.OutputType.FILE)
   screenshot.renameTo(new java.io.File('screenshot.png'))
   WDS.log.info('Page source:')
   WDS.log.info(WDS.browser.getPageSource())
   exception = err
}
finally
{
   throw (exception)
}
```

More information: [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-ten-questions-answered)