# java selenium org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

Tags: java, html, css, selenium, automation

I am a beginner in selenium, I am using java for thatU nill yesterday this code was working well, it showed me same exception for the button named "show". I searched for it and solved it. But again today its showing for clicking on list please help me. Also can I use wait named as domPropertyToBe

My java code:

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.List;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.Assert;

public class erp {

    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {        
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Tools\\Selenium\\Chromedriver96\\chromedriver_win32 (1)\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver dChromedriver=new ChromeDriver();
    dChromedriver.get("https://erp.mitwpu.edu.in/");
    dChromedriver.manage().window().maximize();
        WebElement  txtPassword=dChromedriver.findElement(By.id("txtPassword")) ;
        WebElement txtUserId=dChromedriver.findElement(By.id("txtUserId")) ;
        txtUserId.sendKeys("S1032200787");
        txtPassword.sendKeys("FynS@3XbZH6ZMWH");
        //
        WebDriverWait w =new WebDriverWait(dChromedriver, Duration.ofSeconds(30));
        w.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@id='ReCaptchContainer']")));
        dChromedriver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='ReCaptchContainer']")).click();
//      Thread.sleep(3000);
        w.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("label#lblMessage")));
        WebElement success_lablElement=dChromedriver.findElement(By.cssSelector("label#lblMessage"));
        Assert.assertEquals(success_lablElement.getText(),"Success" );
        dChromedriver.findElement(By.id("btnLogin")).click();
        WebElement resultWebElement=dChromedriver.findElement(By.xpath("//nav[@class=\"mt-2\"]/ul/li[12]/a[@href=\"Examination/Report/StudentGradeCardDetail.aspx?MENU_CODE=Web_Result\"]"));
        resultWebElement.click();
        w.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.id("FrameContent")));
//      w.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("drpSem_Arrow")));
               dChromedriver.findElement(By.id("drpSem_Arrow")).click();
       w.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.tagName("li")));
       List<WebElement> listElement=dChromedriver.findElements(By.tagName("li"));
       w.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("btnshow")));
       WebElement show_buttonElement=dChromedriver.findElement(By.id("btnshow"));

//     dChromedriver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[onclick=\"$find('ReportViewer1').exportReport('PDF');\"]"));
       for (WebElement list : listElement) {

           if (list.getText().equals("SY BTech - CSE / TRIMESTER-V / 2020-21 / Middle"))   {
               list.click();           // This is the line I get error
               show_buttonElement.click();
              
           }
    }
      
    }
//  public static  void myfunction() {
//       try {
//           Robot robot = new Robot();
//     Thread mthread = new Thread(mlauncher);
//         mthread.start();
//
//        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
//        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
//
//       } catch (Exception e) {
//                e.printStackTrace();
//             }
//  }
    

}
```

Comment: At which `element` or line you are getting this exception? Please remove the unnecessary code that is commented.

Comment: At list.click()

Comment: Checkout this https://stackoverflow.com/a/12967602/11863448