# The specified steps pass but the test is invalid

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have the following problem, I want to set exact specific date, month and year. There is no problem for the month and the year. After the end of the test in the date field, everything is as it should be (the values I set), but the problem is that my test failed. According to the error it is something xpath, I tried others but the scenario is the same, exactly set values but the test fails.

```
List<IWebElement> currentDay = _wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.XPath("//div[@class='react-datepicker__month']//*[@role='option']"))).ToList();
foreach (IWebElement day in currentDay)
{
    if (day.Text == "10")
    {
        day.Click();
    }
}
```

And this is the error:

```
 SelectCurrentDate
   Source: UnitTest1.cs line 69
   Duration: 8.9 sec

  Message: 
OpenQA.Selenium.StaleElementReferenceException : stale element reference: stale element not found
  (Session info: chrome=120.0.6099.218)

  Stack Trace: 
RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
RemoteWebElement.get_Text()
Tests.SelectCurrentDate() line 96
RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Void** arguments, Signature sig, Boolean isConstructor)
MethodInvoker.Invoke(Object obj, IntPtr* args, BindingFlags invokeAttr)
```

As soon as the data appears to be set correctly, the test should pass

Comment: It is difficult to tell what the problem is without seeing the full code as well as the actual website being tested. However seeing that you are getting `StaleElementReferenceException` gives a hint of what could possibly be happening. It might be, that there is some updating happening while filling out the form which could trigger this exception. Usually there is not one way to address this issue and there are various ways it could be solved. I would try to pinpoint where the update is happening and would try to wait for that specific update to happen first before working with the element.

Comment: You could go through this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12967541/how-to-avoid-staleelementreferenceexception-in-selenium

You will find many different ways of how to deal with `StaleElementReferenceException` and the reasons for this exception occuring. It is for `Java` but the same principles should apply to any programming language that supports `Selenium`.