# Selenium fluentWait is resulting in a StaleElementReferenceException

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, webdriver

I have a scenario as outlined in the screenshot below:
[image]

So, I've built some code which will allow me to click on the bar charts on the left....each time I do it will display a relational bar chart on the right. If the bar chart is particularly big on the left it might take a while for the relational bar chart on the right to show. To counter this, I built a fluentWait method, as below:

```
    public static void fluentWaitOnRelationalBarChartSelector(InternetExplorerDriver driver)
    {
        WebElement relationalBarSelect = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 20))
                .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.tagName("rect")));
        relationalBarSelect.click();
    }
```

However, not always, but sometimes, I am getting an error in the console as below:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: Element is no longer valid
(WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 33 milliseconds
```

What I'm not sure on is why this timeout is occurring after 33 milliseconds when I have applied a wait of 20 seconds? Is there a way of me being able to cater for this `StaleElementReferenceException`?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just a correction @Andy. `FluentWait` is a class of selenium java binding and mechanism is different then `WebDriverWait` which is a subclass of `FluentWait`. See [this](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.html)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Saifur :-)

Comment: You are welcome. Let me know if the solution works though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StaleElementReferenceException` is a very painful and very specific to the element. It generally means the element is unavailable to interact with selenium due to a lot of issue with some very specific to your set up. To resolve this there are two different mechanism people use(at least according to my knowledge). `FluentWait` will probably save your life. Something like the following:

```
// Waiting 30 seconds for an element to be present on the page, checking
   // for its presence once every 5 seconds.
   Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
       .withTimeout(30, SECONDS)
       .pollingEvery(5, SECONDS)
       .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

   WebElement foo = wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
     public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
       return driver.findElement(By.id("foo"));
     }
   });
```

taken from [here](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.html). It's worth mentioning that it allows you to wait for an element ignoring some other exceptions as well.

If that does not work then estimate a number of loop that might be enough for that element to be ready for interact. Not my favorite but works.

```
public void StaleElementHandleByID (String elementID){
int count = 0; 
while (count < 4){
    try {
       WebElement yourSlipperyElement= driver.findElement(By.id(elementID));
       yourSlipperyElement.click(); 
     } catch (StaleElementReferenceException e){
       e.toString();
       System.out.println("Trying to recover from a stale element :" + e.getMessage());
       count = count+1;
     }
   count = count+4;
}
```

taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4846454/selenium-webdriver-staleelementreferenceexception)

Comment: That's brilliant, Saifur, thank-you. It's worked brilliantly!

Answer (score 0):

Even though nothing on the page visibly changes, there might be JavaScript among other things that change the properties of a `WebElement`, after the page loads. This JavaScript might be triggered by a previous action that your script has performed (Ex: Click on some other `WebElement`).

If you try to interact (click, sendkeys etc...) with the WebElement after it's properties change, selenium will throw a `StaleElementReferenceException`. In such cases, your code should retry the action couple times, rather than throwing an exception on the first try, see below.

```
public static Boolean executeElementClick
  (WebDriver driver, WebElement element, int MaxTimeToWait) throws Exception {
    // Local variable declaration
    String sElementString = "";
    String sElementXpath = "";
    Boolean returnValue = false;
    int index = 0;

    // Set browser timeout to 1 second. Will be reset to default later
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    // Keep trying until 'MaxTimeToWait' is reached 
    for (int loop = 0; loop < MaxTimeToWait; loop++) {
        try {
            // Get element xPath - and find element again
            if (element != null && loop < 1 && sElementXpath.equals("")) {
                sElementString = (element).toString();
                if (sElementString.contains("xpath: ")) {
                    // Retrieve xPath from element, if available
                    index = sElementString.indexOf("xpath: ");
                    sElementXpath = sElementString
                                       .substring(index + 7, sElementString.length());
                }
            }

            // Find Element again
            if (!sElementXpath.equals("") && loop > 0) {
                element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(sElementXpath));
            }

            // Execute the action requested
            element.click();
            returnValue = true;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            returnValue = false;
        }

        if (returnValue) {
            System.out.println("**** PASSED: Clicked on '" + sElementString + "'");
            break;
        }
    }
    // Reset browser timeout to default
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    return returnValue;
}
```