# Selenium Java code to print the first five results from google search

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Exception in thread "main" **org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException:** stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.106)
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.html
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 83.0.4103.106, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 83.0.4103.39 (ccbf011cb2d2b..., userDataDir: C:\Users\MOHAMM~1\AppData\L...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:53846}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: f9fd73fa86d306099bad2835337c25c0
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//h3[@class='LC20lb DKV0Md']}

[Code snap shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NOGU.png)

Results are getting displayed for the first page but when I click on second page results I get StaleElementReferenceException

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class NavigateToGoogle {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='gLFyf gsfi'])")).sendKeys("zahid");

        WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
        element.sendKeys("mohammed zahid");
        //element.click();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        //driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@type='submit'])[3]")).click();
        List<WebElement> button=driver.findElements(By.name("btnK"));
        System.out.println(button.size());
        WebElement submit=driver.findElement(By.name("btnK"));
        submit.submit();

        WebElement matchingRes=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h3[@class='LC20lb DKV0Md']"));
        List<WebElement> listRes=matchingRes.findElements(By.xpath("//h3[@class='LC20lb DKV0Md']"));
        System.out.println(listRes.size());
        for(WebElement results:listRes) 
        {
            String value = results.getText();
            System.out.println(value);
        }

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@aria-label='Page 2']")).click();
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//h3[@class='LC20lb DKV0Md']")));
        WebElement matchingRes1=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h3[@class='LC20lb DKV0Md']")); 
        matchingRes1.getSize();
        List<WebElement> listRes1=matchingRes.findElements(By.xpath("//h3[@class='LC20lb DKV0Md']")); 
        System.out.println(listRes1.size());

        for(WebElement results1:listRes1)
        {
            String value = results1.getText();
            System.out.println(value);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid "StaleElementReferenceException" in Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12967541/how-to-avoid-staleelementreferenceexception-in-selenium)

Comment: Also check;
[Selenium WebDriver How to Resolve Stale Element Reference Exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16166261/selenium-webdriver-how-to-resolve-stale-element-reference-exception)
[Selenium WebDriver StaleElementReferenceException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4846454/selenium-webdriver-staleelementreferenceexception)
[stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18225997/stale-element-reference-element-is-not-attached-to-the-page-document)

Answer (score 0):

We cant hard code google results page elements because every google page is updating day by day.here i have given results search with example code you can try this ( i am lauching google page and type "Testing" and getting all results displayed and click "Testing types" from list , if you need all results you can get print)

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads\\Chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
    driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("Testing");
    Thread.sleep(Long.parseLong("1000"));
    List<WebElement> LIST = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@role='listbox']//li/descendant::div[@class='sbl1']"));
    System.out.println(LIST.size());


    for (int i = 0; i < LIST.size(); i++)
    {
        //System.out.println(LIST.get(i).getText());
        if (LIST.get(i).getText().contains("testing types"))
        {
            LIST.get(i).click();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

}